# Why isn't the 'len' function inherited by dictionaries and lists in Python

Tags: python

example:

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3]
a_list.len() # doesn't work
len(a_list) # works
```

Python being (very) object oriented, I don't understand why the 'len' function isn't inherited by the object. 
Plus I keep trying the wrong solution since it appears as the logical one to me

Comment: Functions aren't inherited. Methods are. Whose object's `len` method would you like to inherit from?

Comment: This is irrelevant since len just calls the __len__ method, so the same inheritance issues will still apply.

Comment: @Eli You mean `__len__` method -- SO interpreted the double underscores as bold. =)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Guido's explanation is [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-November/004643.html):

> First of all, I chose len(x) over x.len() for HCI reasons (def __len__() came much later). There are two intertwined reasons actually, both HCI:
>
> (a) For some operations, prefix notation just reads better than postfix — prefix (and infix!) operations have a long tradition in mathematics which likes notations where the visuals help the mathematician thinking about a problem. Compare the easy with which we rewrite a formula like x*(a+b) into x*a + x*b to the clumsiness of doing the same thing using a raw OO notation.
>
> (b) When I read code that says len(x) I know that it is asking for the length of something. This tells me two things: the result is an integer, and the argument is some kind of container. To the contrary, when I read x.len(), I have to already know that x is some kind of container implementing an interface or inheriting from a class that has a standard len(). Witness the confusion we occasionally have when a class that is not implementing a mapping has a get() or keys() method, or something that isn’t a file has a write() method.
>
> Saying the same thing in another way, I see ‘len‘ as a built-in operation. I’d hate to lose that. /…/

Comment: For those who don't know, HCI stands for Human-Computer Interface.  So when Guido says he made the decision for "HCI reasons" he's saying he thought it made the code more readable.

Comment: @Thomas: Python uses `|` for bitwise OR, just like C does.

Comment: The one where Guido argues generic functions are better than methods. The mind boggles. :/

Answer (score 13):

The short answer: 1) backwards compatibility and 2) there's not enough of a difference for it to really matter.  For a more detailed explanation, read on.

The idiomatic Python approach to such operations is special methods which aren't intended to be called directly.  For example, to make `x + y` work for your own class, you write a `__add__` method.  To make sure that `int(spam)` properly converts your custom class, write a `__int__` method.  To make sure that `len(foo)` does something sensible, write a `__len__` method.

This is how things have always been with Python, and I think it makes a lot of sense for some things.  In particular, this seems like a sensible way to implement operator overloading.  As for the rest, different languages disagree; in Ruby you'd convert something to an integer by calling `spam.to_i` directly instead of saying `int(spam)`.

You're right that Python is an extremely object-oriented language and that having to call an external function on an object to get its length seems odd.  On the other hand, `len(silly_walks)` isn't any more onerous than `silly_walks.len()`, and Guido has said that he actually prefers it (http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-November/004643.html).

Comment: Ah... this finally made sense of it all. len() is more of an operator that a function, really.

Answer (score 11):

It just isn't.

You can, however, do:

```
>>> [1,2,3].__len__()

3
```

Adding a `__len__()` method to a class is what makes the `len()` magic work.

Answer (score 6):

This way fits in better with the rest of the language. The convention in python is that you add `__foo__` special methods to objects to make them have certain capabilities (rather than e.g. deriving from a specific base class). For example, an object is

- callable if it has a `__call__` method
- iterable if it has an `__iter__` method,
- supports access with [] if it has `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.
- ...

One of these special methods is `__len__` which makes it have a length accessible with `len()`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for `__len__`.  If that method exists, then len(a) calls it:

```
>>> class Spam:
...   def __len__(self): return 3
... 
>>> s = Spam()
>>> len(s)
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there actually is a length method, it is just hidden:

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a_list.__len__()
3
```

The len() built-in function appears to be simply a wrapper for a call to the hidden **len**() method of the object.

Not sure why they made the decision to implement things this way though.

Answer (score 2):

there is some good info below on why certain things are functions and other are methods.  It does indeed cause some inconsistencies in the language.

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-January/076612.html