# Why does Python code use len() function instead of a length method?

Tags: python

I know that python has a `len()` function that is used to determine the size of a string, but I was wondering why it's not a method of the string object?

Comment: Related to your update: [Is there any case where `len(someObj)` does not call `someObj`'s `__len__` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496009/4518341) tl;dr Yes, so always use `len()` instead of `__len__()`.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Strings do have a length method: `__len__()`

The protocol in Python is to implement this method on objects which have a length and use the built-in [`len()`](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/built-in-funcs.html#l2h-45) function, which calls it for you, similar to the way you would implement `__iter__()` and use the built-in `iter()` function (or have the method called behind the scenes for you) on objects which are iterable.

See [Emulating container types](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/sequence-types.html) for more information.

Here's a good read on the subject of protocols in Python: [Python and the Principle of Least Astonishment](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/)

Comment: It astonishes me how moronic the reason for using `len` is. They think that it is easier to force people to implement `.__len__` than to force people to implement `.len()`. Its the same thing, and one looks _much_ cleaner. If the language is going to have an OOP `__len__`, what in the world is the point of making `len(..)`

Comment: len, str, etc. can be used with higher-order functions like map, reduce, and filter without the need to define a function or lambda just to call a method. Not everything revolves around OOP, even in Python.

Comment: Also, by using a protocol, they can provide alternative ways of implementing things. For example, you can create an iterable with `__iter__`, or with only `__getitem__`, and `iter(x)` will work either way. You can create a usable-in-bool-context object with `__bool__` or `__len__`, and `bool(x)` will work either way. And so on. I think Armin explains this reasonably well in the linked post—but even if he didn't, calling Python moronic because of an outside explanation by a guy who's often publicly at odds with the core devs wouldn't exactly be fair…

Comment: @Evicatos: +1 for "Not everything revolves around OOP", but I'd end with "_especially_ in Python", not _even_. Python (unlike Java, Ruby, or Smalltalk) doesn't try to be a "pure OOP" language; it's explicitly designed to be a "multi-paradigm" language. List comprehensions aren't methods on iterables. `zip` is a top-level function, not a `zip_with` method. And so on. Just because everything is an object doesn't mean being an object is the most important thing about each thing.

Comment: That article is so poorly written I feel confused and angry after trying to read it.

"In Python 2.x the Tuple type for instance does not expose any non-special methods and yet you can use it to make a string out of it:"

The whole thing is an amalgamation of near-indecipherable sentences.

Comment: “Now if you are asking, why is it x.next() and not next(x): an oversight that was corrected with Python 3” lol if this syntax were really such a natural way of thinking they wouldn’t have made this mistake in the first place…

Answer (score 117):

Jim's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83983/why-isnt-the-len-function-inherited-by-dictionaries-and-lists-in-python) may help; I copy it here. Quoting Guido van Rossum:

> First of all, I chose len(x) over x.len() for HCI reasons (def __len__() came much later). There are two intertwined reasons actually, both HCI:
>
> (a) For some operations, prefix notation just reads better than postfix — prefix (and infix!) operations have a long tradition in mathematics which likes notations where the visuals help the mathematician thinking about a problem. Compare the easy with which we rewrite a formula like x*(a+b) into x*a + x*b to the clumsiness of doing the same thing using a raw OO notation.
>
> (b) When I read code that says len(x) I know that it is asking for the length of something. This tells me two things: the result is an integer, and the argument is some kind of container. To the contrary, when I read x.len(), I have to already know that x is some kind of container implementing an interface or inheriting from a class that has a standard len(). Witness the confusion we occasionally have when a class that is not implementing a mapping has a get() or keys() method, or something that isn’t a file has a write() method.
>
> Saying the same thing in another way, I see ‘len‘ as a built-in operation. I’d hate to lose that. /…/

Comment: 200+  votes says that the lack of str.len() wastes a ton of people's time coming here and reading why it "should be" intuitive that a string does not have a length function :facepalm:    By all means retain the built-in len() function, but why not _also_ support sensible methods on basic things like strings...

Answer (score 43):

Python is a pragmatic programming language, and the reasons for `len()` being a function and not a method of `str`, `list`, `dict` etc. are pragmatic.

The `len()` built-in function deals directly with built-in types: the CPython implementation of `len()` actually returns the value of the `ob_size` field in the [`PyVarObject` C struct](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8c8315bac6a8/Include/object.h#l111) that represents any variable-sized built-in object in memory. This is **much** faster than calling a method -- no attribute lookup needs to happen. Getting the number of items in a collection is a common operation and must work efficiently for such basic and diverse types as `str`, `list`, `array.array` etc.

However, to promote consistency, when applying `len(o)` to a user-defined type, Python calls `o.__len__()` as a fallback.  `__len__`, `__abs__` and all the other special methods documented in the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html) make it easy to create objects that behave like the built-ins, enabling the expressive and highly consistent APIs we call "Pythonic".

By implementing special methods your objects can support iteration, overload infix operators, manage contexts in **`with`** blocks etc. You can think of the Data Model as a way of using the Python language itself as a framework where the objects you create can be integrated seamlessly.

A second reason, supported by quotes from Guido van Rossum like [this one](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm), is that it is easier to read and write `len(s)` than `s.len()`.

The notation `len(s)` is consistent with unary operators with prefix notation, like `abs(n)`. `len()` is used way more often than `abs()`, and it deserves to be as easy to write.

There may also be a historical reason: in the ABC language which preceded Python (and was very influential in its design), there was a unary operator written as `#s` which meant `len(s)`.

Comment: I do not buy the optimality argument. While a method call could indeed be slower, a sufficiently advanced interpreter or compiler –and  Python interpreters do much more advanced things than this– could recognize that one is calling the `len` method of a built-in type and revert to returning `ob_size` or whatever it needs, at least the vast majority of the time.

Comment: @dionyziz: Python's algorithm to look up attributes is very flexible. You have instance attributes, class attributes, data descriptors, not-data descriptors, and multiple-inheritance. All that may play a role in a call like `s.len()`, but does not affect `len(s)`.

Answer (score 36):

There is a `len` method:

```
>>> a = 'a string of some length'
>>> a.__len__()
23
>>> a.__len__
<method-wrapper '__len__' of str object at 0x02005650>
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not meant to be used directly. `len` validates the output of `__len__`. See [Is there any case where `len(someObj)` does not call `someObj`'s `__len__` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496009/4518341) Dunder methods in general are not meant to be called directly.

Answer (score 11):

```
met% python -c 'import this' | grep 'only one'
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
```

Comment: The obvious thing when working with an object being, of course, a method.

Comment: @Peter: I'd pay $20 to anyone with photo evidence that they taped your comment to Guido's back.  $50 if it's on his forehead.

Comment: Yeah, the Python designers adhere to dogma but they themselves don't respect their own dogma.

Comment: $ python -c 'import this' | grep obvious

Answer (score 6):

Something missing from the rest of the answers here: the `len` function checks that the `__len__` method returns a non-negative `int`. The fact that `len` is a function means that classes cannot override this behaviour to avoid the check. As such, `len(obj)` gives a level of safety that `obj.len()` cannot.

Example:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 'foo'
...
>>> len(A())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    len(A())
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>> class B:
...     def __len__(self):
...         return -1
... 
>>> len(B())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    len(B())
ValueError: __len__() should return >= 0
```

Of course, it is possible to "override" the `len` function by reassigning it as a global variable, but code which does this is much more obviously suspicious than code which overrides a method in a class.

Comment: It also checks that the int is not greater than `sys.maxsize`, and that `obj.__len__` exists in the first place. I wrote [an answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59604139/4518341) that lists all the different checks.

Answer (score 4):

There are some great answers here, and so before I give my own I'd like to highlight a few of the gems (no ruby pun intended) I've read here.

- Python is not a pure OOP language -- it's a general purpose, multi-paradigm language that allows the programmer to use the paradigm they are most comfortable with and/or the paradigm that is best suited for their solution.
- Python has first-class functions, so `len` is actually an object. Ruby, on the other hand, doesn't have first class functions. So the `len` function object has it's own methods that you can inspect by running `dir(len)`.

If you don't like the way this works in your own code, it's trivial for you to re-implement the containers using your preferred method (see example below).

```
>>> class List(list):
...     def len(self):
...         return len(self)
...
>>> class Dict(dict):
...     def len(self):
...         return len(self)
...
>>> class Tuple(tuple):
...     def len(self):
...         return len(self)
...
>>> class Set(set):
...     def len(self):
...         return len(self)
...
>>> my_list = List([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F'])
>>> my_dict = Dict({'key': 'value', 'site': 'stackoverflow'})
>>> my_set = Set({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F'})
>>> my_tuple = Tuple((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F'))
>>> my_containers = Tuple((my_list, my_dict, my_set, my_tuple))
>>>
>>> for container in my_containers:
...     print container.len()
...
15
2
15
15
```

Comment: You forgot to re-implement String, we like to know the length of those quite often ;) If one is the kind of person who wish to bend the language at its likings, this person will be more comfortable in Ruby, where he can add and overload methods to existing classes. Instead of defining a new class to add just one method. bye

Comment: @NicolaMingotti no, I did not forget to implement string... I think you're unable to tell the difference between an example and a suggestion.

Comment: You failed to get the irony. Without the irony: You example/suggestion/snippet is just bad, it is a bad idea. I hope nobody will ever wish to copy it. Indeed it would require to redefine basically all Python basic types. In a language as Python (One Way To Do It) this is can be considered the worst syle: just use len(). bye

Comment: What you do not understand ? You provide a solution. I consider it a bad solution and a bad practice for Python (not in general). Beginners will find and use (copy) what you propose, this is undesirable.

Comment: (1) The issue of the missing ".len" is still there and kicking. (2) Your distinction about example and solution is sterile. It is there written, if you don't write also, well visible, DON'T DO THIS, JUST FOR ILLUSTRATION, many will use it. (3) you proposed it so you are responsible for the spread of this bad practice. I will not elaborate further. have a nice day.