# Is there any case where len(someObj) does not call someObj's __len__ function?

Tags: python, magic-methods

Is there any case where `len(someObj)` does not call someObj's `__len__` function?

I recently replaced the former with the latter in a (sucessful) effort to speed up some code.  I want to make sure there's not some edge case somewhere where `len(someObj)` is not the same as `someObj.__len__()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `__len__` returns a length over `sys.maxsize`, `len()` will raise an exception. This isn't true of calling `__len__` directly. (In fact you could return any object from `__len__` which won't be caught unless it goes through `len()`.)

Comment: Note that, since `len` is supposed to be return the number of elements in a collection, returning something bigger than `sys.maxsize` is almost certainly nonsense.

Comment: @Mike In theory you could have an object like Python 3's `range` that doesn't store all its elements in memory and calculates its `__len__` using math. `range.__len__` itself raises an error in that situation: `range(sys.maxsize+1).__len__()` gives `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t`

Comment: Note that the above is only true in 2.x. In 3.6, for example, I get `len(range(1000000000000))` -> `1000000000000`, and (worryingly) `range(1000000000000).__len__()` -> `-727379968`. Although this result still shows why you shouldn't call `__len__` yourself!

Comment: `len` also raises an exception if the value returned by `__len__` is negative, or not an `int`.

Answer (score 12):

What kind of speedup did you see? I cannot imagine it was noticeable was it?

From http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-May/147079.html

> in certain situations there is no
>   difference, but using len() is
>   preferred  for a couple reasons.
>
> first, it's not recommended to go
>   calling the `__methods__` yourself, they
>   are meant to be used by other parts of
>   python.
>
> `len()` will work on any type of
>   sequence object (`lists`, `tuples`, and
>   all). 
>   `__len__` will only work on class instances with a `__len__` method.
>
> `len()` will return a more appropriate
>   exception on objects without length.

Comment: It was about half a second on a program that ran for one minute.  It's probably because I called len 2,443,519 times.  As I was writing the question I realized that I should probably reduce the number of times I'm calling len.

Comment: @David: Yeah you missed mentioning the 2,443,519 part. Holy hell ;)

Comment: I personally wouldn't consider the extra 1/120th speedup to make it worth the code ugliness, but that's your call.

Comment: @Eli, Normally I would agree with you.  In this case I'm trying to benchmark the same problem in multiple languages.

Comment: FYI: I was able to remove 2,363,276 of those calls to len and that sped things up by another second and a half.

Comment: @DavidLocke: I would think a benchmark based on idiomatic code for each language would be much more useful than one based on bent and mangled code.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is that it will always work -- according to the Python docs:

```
__len__(self):
```

Called to implement the built-in function len(). Should return the length of the object, an integer >= 0. Also, an object that doesn't define a `__nonzero__()` method and whose `__len__()` method returns zero is considered to be false in a Boolean context.

Answer (score 3):

There are cases where `len(someObj)` is not the same as `someObj.__len__()` since `len()` validates `__len__()`'s return value. Here are the possible errors in Python 3.6.9:

- Too low, i.e. less than 0

  ```
  ValueError: __len__() should return >= 0
  ```
- Too high, i.e. greater than `sys.maxsize` (CPython-specific, per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__))

  ```
  OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
  ```
- An invalid type, e.g `float`

  ```
  TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
  ```
- Missing, e.g. `len(object)`

  ```
  TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
  ```

  I mention this because `object.__len__()` raises a different exception, `AttributeError`.

It's also worth noting that `range(sys.maxsize+1)` is valid, but its `__len__()` raises an exception:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

Answer (score -4):

According to Mark Pilgrim, it looks like no.  `len(someObj)` is the same as `someObj.__len__()`;

Cheers!