# How to check if len is valid

Tags: python

I have a function

```
def foo(bar):
    #do some things
    len(bar)
```

If I call

```
foo(42)
```

it throws an exception of

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

How do I check if the entered value can be used with len()?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do:

```
if hasattr(bar, '__len__'):
    pass
```

Alternatively, you can catch the TypeError.

Comment: Wouldn't this need to be `__len__ in dir(bar)`? Either way, using `hasattr` is better if you go with this approach

Comment: Even an object has `__len__` attribute, it doesn't mean it's valid (or OP should define what is **valid**). For example, a class can define a `__len__` function which returns a `str`, and it will pass the `hasattr` test but still throw the `TypeError` exception when you call `len()` on it. This is exactly what **exception handling** is designed for, punish them for giving me dirty input.

Answer (score 25):

You can test if the object is [`Sized`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sized):

```
import collections.abc

if isinstance(bar, collections.abc.Sized):
```

The `isinstance()` test is true if all abstract methods of `Sized` are implemented; in this case that's just `__len__`.

Personally, I'd just catch the exception instead:

```
try:
    foo(42)
except TypeError:
    pass  # oops, no length
```

Answer (score 8):

Since [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) [calls `__len__()` magic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481421/difference-between-len-and-len) under the hood, you can check if an object has `__len__` method defined with the help of [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
>>> def has_len(obj):
...     return hasattr(obj, '__len__')
... 
>>> has_len([1,2,3])
True
>>> has_len('test')
True
>>> has_len(1)
False
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using `try` and `except` for best results:

```
def foo(bar):
    #do some things
    try:
        print(len(bar))
    except TypeError:
        print('Input not compatible with len()')
```

Comment: As a general rule, that's arguably the most Pythonic, duck-typing approach. It doesn't work for some use cases, e.g. list or dict comprehensions.