# Map key to length of value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create another dictionary where the output will be

```py
new_dic = {key: len(value)}
```

Given a dictionary containing lists in its values.

Example:

```py
dic = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5], 'c':[6]}
```

And I want to create `new_dic` from `dic` where the `new_dic` map keys to length of value like this:

```py
new_dic = {'a':3, 'b':2, 'c':1}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Right now what you've posted isn't syntactically valid and `dic['c']` doesn't actually _have_ a length (`len(6)` -> `TypeError`).

Comment: Take a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) which covers "dictionary comprehensions".

Answer (score 2):

Not much to explain here.

`new_dic = {d:len(dic[d]) if type(dic[d]) in {tuple,list,dict} else 1 for d in dic}`

Comment: doesn't work if you have a int and not a list

Comment: @OmerDagry I have added the necessary suggestion

Answer (score 0):

this will work even if you have an `int` not inside a `list` as the `value` in the `dict`

```
dic = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5] , 'c':6}
new_dic = {key: len(val) if type(val) in [tuple, list] else 1 for key, val in dic.items()}
print(new_dic)
```

Comment: doesn't work if you have None and not a list.

Comment: it works, just puts 1 (unless he wants a zero if the value is None but he didn't say if that is what he wants)

Answer (score 0):

you can use what we call a dictionary comprehension :

```
new_dic = {key : len(value) for key, value in dic.items()}
```

Note : `len()` functions works only on iterables (list, tuples...) and not on single values, so to use this you'll have to have your single-values also stored in a list (`'c' : [6]` instead of `'c' : 6`)

Answer (score 0):

```
getlength = lambda obj: len(obj) if hasattr(obj, '__len__') else 1

dic = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5] , 'c':6}

new_dic = {key: getlength(value) for key, value in dic.items()}
print(new_dic.items())
```

The `getlength` checks if the object has the `__len__` method and returns the length or 1, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23567686/6464041) answer.
Then it's just a simple `dict` comprehension.

Output:

```
dict_items([('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)])
```

Comment: `None` has length 1?

Comment: `None` is still one element, but you can just change the `getlength` function to have differing lengths for specific types.

Comment: Furthermore, I imagine a string would have to be considered of length 1 (1 object). But indeed, that can be treated by modifying the function.

Comment: it wasn't specified in the 'question', I assumed a non-iterable object to have length 1