# Python: L1-norm of a sparse non-square matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, norm

I have one problem while try to computing the 1-norm of a sparse matrix. I am using the function `scipy.sparse.linalg.onenormest` but it gives me an error because the operator can act only onto square matrix.

Here a code example:

```
from scipy import sparse

row = array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
col = array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
data = array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

A = sparse.csc_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(5,3) )

onenormest(A)
```

this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_onenormest.py", line 76, in onenormest
    raise ValueError('expected the operator to act like a square matrix')
ValueError: expected the operator to act like a square matrix
```

The operator `onenormest` works if I define A as a square matrix, but this is not what I want.

Anyone knows how to calculate the 1-norm of a sparse non-square matrix?

Comment: Do you actually want the [`L^1-norm`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L1-Norm.html)? I don't know what the `1-norm` is.

Comment: Exactly, so in this example the L1-norm must be 15

Comment: Don't you mean it should be 21?

Comment: Actually I want to replicate the Matlab norm(X,p) function. Where X is my sparse matrix and p = 1. Matlab gives as a result 15. Basically is the highest L1-norm among all the column of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want [numpy.linalg.norm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) instead;

```
from numpy import linalg
from scipy import sparse


row = array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
col = array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
data = array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

A = sparse.csc_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(5,3) )

print linalg.norm(A.todense(), ord=1) #15
```

It does not work to call A.data, since `.data` of a sparse matrix object is just the data - it appears as a vector instead.

If your sparse matrix is only small, then this is fine. If it is large, then obviously this is a problem. In which case, you can write your own routine.

If you are only interested in the `L^1-norm`, and casting to dense is not possible, then you could do it via something like this:

```
def sparseL1Norm = lambda A: max([numpy.abs(A).getcol(i).sum() for i in range(A.shape[1])])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but the operator norm is not working with sparse matrices.

Comment: FYI, i have a strong suspicion that @unutbu's `np.abs(A).sum(axis=0).max()` will perform better, especially for large matrices.

Answer (score 1):

This finds the L1-norm of each column:

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

row = np.array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
col = np.array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
data = np.array([1,2,3,-4,-5,-6]) # made negative to exercise abs
A = sparse.csc_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(5,3) )
print(abs(A).sum(axis=0))
```

yields

```
[[ 3  3 15]]
```

You could then take the max to find the L1-norm of the matrix:

```
print(abs(A).sum(axis=0).max())
# 15
```

---

`abs(A)` is a sparse matrix:

```
In [29]: abs(A)
Out[29]: 
<5x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

and `sum` and `max` are methods of the sparse matrix, so `abs(A).sum(axis=0).max()` computes the L1-norm without densifying the matrix.

Note: Most NumPy functions (such a np.abs) are not designed to work with sparse matrices. Although `np.abs(A)` returns the correct result, it arrives there through an indirect route. The more direct route is to use `abs(A)` which calls `A.__abs__()`. [Thanks to pv.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781315/python-l1-norm-of-a-sparse-non-square-matrix/26781792?noredirect=1#comment42143986_26781792) for point this out.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. But what I would like to have is the same behavior of the Matlab norm(X,p) function, which gives as a result 15. 15 is the L1 norm of the third column of A, which is the higher L1 norm (first column norm = 4, second column norm = 3, third column norm = 15)

Comment: This does not work, since `A.data` for a sparse matrix is just `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`

Comment: Yes exactly. So the result is then 21. But if for example I define

    A = sparse.csc_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(5,5) )

and then I calculate
    
    onenormest(A)

the result is 15, so is working for square sparse matrix, but not with non-square matrix :(

Comment: `np.abs(A).sum(axis=0).max()` is much neater than my solution :/

Comment: Do `abs(A).sum(axis=0).max()` instead. `np.abs` goes via some indirect route to call `A.__abs__()`, as you can verify with `pdb.runcall(np.abs, A)`, whereas `abs(A)` calls it directly. In general, Numpy routines and sparse matrices do not work together as of currently.

Comment: @pv.: Thanks very much for the correction and information.

Comment: `A.__abs__().sum(axis=0).max()` makes it clear that you are using the `abs` defined for the sparse matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj: True, but the general rule is to ["never call a magic method directly (but always indirectly through a built-in) unless you know exactly why you need to do that"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2481631/190597).

Comment: In this case there seems to an ambiguity, or at least misunderstandings, as to whether `abs` or `np.abs` is the desired call.

Comment: @hpaulj: I know my opinion on matters of style have shifted and probably will continue to change as time goes on. But currently I believe ideally, code should be written in a way an expert would deem correct but with enough bread crumbs (e.g. in the form of comments) that an intelligent novice would understand. Therefore I'm reluctant to change `abs(A)` to `A.__abs__` since experts like Martelli and pv. probably wouldn't do that.