# Does Ruby have a built-in getitem method?

Tags: python, ruby

In Python, there is a built-in method called `__getitem__`, which you can add to your classes to make a custom implementation of getting an item. For example:

```
class containerlist (object):

  def __init__(self, *args):
      self.container = [x for x in args]

  def __getitem__(self, i):
      return self.container[i]
```

In Ruby, is there an equivalent for this or other Python built-ins like `__len__` or `__contains__`?

Comment: This question is basically *"how do you Ruby?"* and, therefore, too broad.

Comment: What does this have to do with either rubymine or irb?

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, you access items using `[]`, the method is called, well, `[]`.

Comment: In the case of Hash and Array, where this convention is also used for other things to keep the interface feeling familiar.

Answer (score 3):

Just to illustrate @Jörg W Mittag

```
class Containerlist
  def initialize( *args)
    @container = args
  end

  def [](i)
    @container[i]
  end
end

cl = Containerlist.new(3,4,5) #new creates a new obj and calls initialize 
p cl[1] #interpreted as cl.[](1) # => 4
```

About `__len__` : [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481421/difference-between-len-and-len), Python interprets `len(a_list)` as `a_list.__len__`, to accommodate beginning users. Ruby prefers `size` and/or `length` and does no such thing - it's just `a_list.size` . So:

```
class Containerlist
  def size
    @container.size
  end
end
p cl.size # => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

length of an array (also hashes) in ruby can written in  (at least i know) two ways. calling `length` or `count` methods for an object. for string onjects you can use `length` method

```
irb(main):001:0> x = "some string"
=> "some string"
irb(main):002:0> x.class
=> String
irb(main):003:0> x.length
=> 11
irb(main):005:0> y = (1..9).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):006:0> y.length
=> 9
irb(main):007:0> y.count
=> 9
irb(main):008:0>
```

`__contains__` equivalent in ruby may be `include?` method. actually it's more likely to `in` keyword.

```
irb(main):008:0> x.include?('s')
=> true
irb(main):009:0> y.include?('2')
=> false
irb(main):010:0> y.include?(2)
=> true
```

`find_index` for arrays and `index` for string may be helpful.

```
irb(main):013:0> y.find_index(3)
=> 2
irb(main):016:0> x.index('s')
=> 0
irb(main):017:0> x.index('s', 4) #the second argument is offset value. 
=> 5
```

I am not an experienced rubyist but hope these would be helpful for first steps. Also hope, not to mislead you on your ruby path :)

Comment: `count` may return the correct result but it's the wrong method to call in such cases. See [The Elements of Style in Ruby #13: Length vs Size vs Count](http://batsov.com/articles/2014/02/17/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-13-length-vs-size-vs-count/)