# The reason of foo.__x__ and x(foo) in Python (i.e. len and __len__)

Tags: python, python-internals

Intuitively a `List` class should implement an attribute or a method to retrieve the length of the instance. Fortunately Python'lists have a hidden method called `__len__`. Unfortunately this method is not meant to be used directly. I should instead use an external function that will read the hidden method for me.

It is like I need to ask someone else to open the fridge to grab a beer for me. The beer is in the fridge, I have ma both hands and I should be able to do it myself.

Conceptually this approach seems curious. Why not having an attribute, (rather than a method) for getting the length of a list.

In other words, I would prefer using `foo.len` instead of `foo.len()` or `foo.__len__`. `len(foo)` appears more bizarre to me.

Is there an explanation for this implementation?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481433/2612235) answers partially my question, but my frustration remains.

Comment: [This](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm) may be worth reading.

Comment: As well as [this one](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/) (took some time to find again).

Comment: @MathiasEttinger both articles answer my question. I understand the philosophy behind and I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a deep rationale [here](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/) and Guido's thoughts [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm).

For a summary, it’s because they might not be as closely related as you might think. Just talking about the `len` vs. `__len__` of your post but you can find other examples in the first link.

Let's start by focusing on `__len__`:

```
class Test1:
    pass

class Test2:
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

class Test3:
    def __len__(self):
        return 0

t1 = Test1()
t2 = Test2()
t3 = Test3()
```

Now what is the evaluation of `t1`, `t2`¹, and `t3` in a boolean context?

- `bool(t1)` is `True`. Standard python behaviour, anything that is not explicitly `False` is considered `True`.
- `bool(t2)` is `False`. Explicitly setting an object to `False` behaves accordingly.
- `bool(t3)` is `False`. Since `t3` implements `__len__` is considered to be a container and since its length is `0` then it’s an empty one. By definition, an empty container is considered `False` in a boolean context.

`__len__` is not bound to be called only by `len`.

`len`, on the other hand, offers you guaranties:

- it will return a positive integer;
- it will work on any container, not only lists;
- it will count the number of elements in that container. Whatever it means is dependent of the container though: compare

  ```
  s = "A string with "
  d = s.encode("utf-8")
  print(len(s)) # outputs 15
  print(len(d)) # outputs 18
  ```

  because `s` is a container of characters and `d` is a container of bytes.

---

¹ Note that `__bool__` was `__nonzero__` in python2.