# return random values from a stack python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, stack

I am trying to return 5 values from a stack and displaying it out. May I ask how I can go about doing it?

Attached is my code on how to solve the problem.

```
import random
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def isEmpty(self):
         return self.size() == 0   

    def push(self, item):
         self.stack.append(item)  

    def peek(self) :
         if self.size()>0 :
             return self.stack[-1]
         else :
             return None

    def pop(self):
         return self.stack.pop()  

    def size(self):
         return len(self.stack)

    def randomFive(self):
        return self[random.randint(0,len(self)-1)]
list = Stack()
list.push("Tom")
list.push("John")
list.push("Peter")
list.push("Harry")
list.push("Jerry")

for i in range(0, list.size()):
    five = list.randomFive()
```

The error shown is:

```
return self[random.randint(0,len(self)-1)]    
TypeError: object of type 'Stack' has no len()
```

Comment: try to not overwrite names of built-in objects like `list`

Comment: also `self[random.randint(0,len(self)-1)]` probably should be `self[random.randint(0,len(self.stack)-1)]` or you should define `__len__` method

Comment: I have tried both methods but there is still an error which says    
    `return(self[random.randint(0,len(self.stack)-1)])
    AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'stack`

Answer (score 1):

Error is caused by statement in `randomFive` method

```
self[random.randint(0,len(self)-1)]
```

because `self` is an instance of `Stack` which has no [`__len__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) available and for user-defined classes [`len` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) tries to call it and raises an error if there is no any (more info at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481421/difference-between-len-and-len)).

Fast fix would be to change it to

```
self[random.randint(0,len(self.stack)-1)]
```

but in longer perspective it will be better to define your own `__len__` method like

```
class Stack:
    ...
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.stack)
```

after that your original `randomFive` method should work.