# How can a same entity function as a parameter as well as an object?

Tags: python-3.x

In the below operation, we are using **a** as an object as well as an argument.

a = "Hello, World!"

1. print(***a*.lower()**)  -> ***a*** as an object
2. print(**len(*a*)**)   -> ***a*** as a parameter

May I know how exactly each operations differs in the way they are accessing **a**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481421/difference-between-len-and-len

Answer (score 1):

Everything in python (everything that can go on the rhs of an assignment) is an object, so what you can pass as an argument to a function IS an object, always. Actually, those are totally orthogonal concepts: you don't "use" something "as an object" - it IS an object - but you can indeed "use it" (pass it) as an argument to a function / method / whatever callable.

> May I know how exactly each operations differs in the way they are accessing a?

Not by much actually (except for the fact they do different things with `a`)...

`a.lower()` is only syntactic sugar for `str.lower(a)` (`obj.method()` is syntactic sugar for `type(obj).method(obj)`, so in both cases you are "using `a` as an argument".