# python __getattr__ doesn't work for built-in functions

Tags: python, built-in, getattr

I'm trying to build some kind of generic wrapper class to hold variable objects.

```
class Var:
    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        self.obj=obj

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.obj, attr)
```

Now for example, when I try to use it with `list` as `obj`, I get different behavior when calling `__len__` attribute or `len` built-in function.

```
v1 = Var([1,2,3])

print(v1.__len__())
# output: 3

print(len(v1))
# output: TypeError: object of type 'Var' has no len()
```

That happens with other built-in functions as well. My questions are:

1. What in those functions implementation is causing the different behavior.
2. How can I bring `Var` class to work with `len` as well.

Comment: I suggest using https://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement your own `__len__` method inside `Var` class. Something like this:

```
class Var:
    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        self.obj=obj

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.obj, attr)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.obj)

v1 = Var([1,2,3])

print(v1.__len__())
print(len(v1))
```

output:

```
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~/test$ python len.py 
3
3
```

And here you have some information about differences between `len()` and `__len__`: [Difference between len() and .__len__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481421/difference-between-len-and-len)

Comment: Yes, that's an option, but I prefer not to implement every python predefined function this way. It'll be nice to find a generic way to do so.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why is necessary for you to do `len()` on instances?

Comment: `len()` is not the issue. I want to be able to call any functions on `Var` object and to get the results of this function on the internal object.

Comment: So here you have an example if I understood the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28579925/2156813

Comment: "What are you trying to do?" This seems useful when creating wrappers. When wrapping a list for example you often want `__len__` and `__getitem__`. I think also `__iter__`, `__delitem__`? There are quite a few you need to specify when wrapping objects.