# Should I use python magic methods directly?

Tags: python, magic-methods

I heard from one guy that you should not use magic methods directly. and I think in some use cases I would have to use magic methods directly. So experienced devs, should I use python magic methods directly?

Comment: No you shouldn't. All "magic" methods have an equivalent built-in function or syntax for calling them

Comment: You should when you need the specific job they do, but most magic methods are only responsible for *part* of what you might think their job is. For example, `__add__` is not responsible for the entirety of a `+` operation, `__getattribute__` is not the whole attribute access protocol, and not all iterables have an `__iter__` method.

Comment: One of those relatively rare times when the thing you "heard from one guy" was actually right. Now might be a good time to play the lottery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I intended to show some benefits of **not** using magic methods directly:

1- Readability:

Using built-in functions like `len()` is much more readable than its relevant magic/special method `__len__()`. Imagine a source code full of only magic methods instead of built-in function... thousands of underscores...

---

2- Comparison operators:

```
class C:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        print('__lt__ called')

class D:
    pass

c = C()
d = D()

d > c
d.__gt__(c)
```

I haven't implemented `__gt__` for neither of those classes, but in `d > c` when Python sees that class `D` doesn't have `__gt__`, it checks to see if class `C` implements `__lt__`. It does, so we get `'__lt__ called'` in output which isn't the case with `d.__gt__(c)`.

---

3- Extra checks:

```
class C:
    def __len__(self):
        return 'boo'

obj = C()
print(obj.__len__())  # fine
print(len(obj))       # error
```

or:

```
class C:
    def __str__(self):
        return 10

obj = C()
print(obj.__str__())  # fine
print(str(obj))       # error
```

As you see, when Python calls that magic methods implicitly, [it does some extra checks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699503/13944524) as well.

---

4- This is the least important but using let's say `len()` on built-in data types such as `str` gives a little bit of speed as compared to `__len__()`:

```
from timeit import timeit

string = 'abcdefghijklmn'

print(timeit("len(string)", globals=globals(), number=10_000_000))
print(timeit("string.__len__()", globals=globals(), number=10_000_000))
```

output:

```
0.5442426
0.8312854999999999
```

It's because of the lookup process(`__len__` in the namespace), If you create a bound method before timing, it's gonna be faster.

```py
bound_method = string.__len__
print(timeit("bound_method()", globals=globals(), number=10_000_000))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a senior developer, but my experience says that you shouldn't call magic methods directly.

Magic methods should be used to override a behavior on your object. For example, if you want to define how does your object is built, you override `__init__`. Afterwards when you want to initialize it, you use `MyNewObject()` instead of `MyNewObject.__init__()`.

For me, I tend to appreciate the answer given by Alex Martelli [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481631/4282400):

> When you see a call to the `len` built-in, you're sure that, if the program continues after that rather than raising an exception, the call has returned an integer, non-negative, and less than 2**31 -- when you see a call to `xxx.__len__()`, you have no certainty (except that the code's author is either unfamiliar with Python or up to no good;-).

If you want to know more about Python's magic methods, I strongly recommend taking a look on this documentation made by Rafe Kettler: https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/

Answer (score 1):

No you shouldn't.

it's ok to be used in quick code problems like in hackerrank but not in production code. when I asked this question I used them as first class functions. what I mean is, I used `xlen = x.__mod__` instead of `xlen = lamda y: x % y` which was more convenient. it's ok to use these kinda snippets in simple programs but not in any other case.