# Why does print(t) error if t.__str__() returns a non-string, but not print(t.__str__())?

Tags: python, type-conversion, typeerror, magic-methods

I am trying to understand the `__str__` method in Python.

```py
class Test:
    def __str__(self):
        return 5

t = Test()

print(t.__str__())
```

In this method it returns an integer value but the print method is able to print it.

But, when I tried `print(t)` it threw the error  `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)`.

As I understand `print(t)` is also calling the `__str__(self)` method.

Why didn't `print(t.__str__())` want the the string type conversion?

Comment: `print(t.__str__())` avoids the error because it becomes `print(5)` after explicitly calling the method.

Comment: Whereas `print(t)` returns an error for the same reason `str(t)` does. You can't make a string out of `t` (as `print()` must, to output its value), due to the bad implementation of `__str__()`.

Comment: At some level, it doesn't really matter: it's implementation-dependent undefined behavior. The `__str__` method documents that "[its] return value must be a string object".

Comment: Today, `t.__str__()` could happily return a non-`str` value; tomorrow, it could raise an exception, and that would not be a breaking change, because the language never defined what should happen if `__str__` doesn't return a string.

Comment: (Take `__init__`: it's a `TypeError` to return any value other than `None`, though I vaguely recall that it was once legal, even if any return value from the implicit call during object creation would be ignored.)

Answer (score 32):

What you’re doing is equivalent to `print(5)`, which works because `print` calls `__str__` on `5` to get a string. But passing the object, `print` calls `__str__` on the object and *doesn’t* get an actual string in response.

Answer (score 29):

It's all about extra checks that python does with some **built-in** functions.

```
len() --> __len__() + some checks
str() --> __str__() + some checks
```

There is a difference between when "you" call a method explicitly or when that method gets called "by Python"! The point is when Python calls your method it will do some **checks** for you. (That's one of the reasons that we should use those built-in functions instead of calling relevant dunder method.)

We can see that behavior with `len()` and `__len__()` as well:

```
class Test:
    def __len__(self):
        return 'foo'

t = Test()

print(t.__len__())  # fine
print(len(t))       # TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

So python checked for returning integer in second print statement! that's what expected from `__len__()`.

Same thing happens here. When you call `print(t)` [Python itself calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) `__str__()` method, so it **does** check to see if `__str__()` returns a string that is expected or not. (same thing happens with `str(t)`)

But, when you say `print(t.__str__())`, first, you're calling it's `__str__()` method on the instance explicitly by yourself, there is no checking here... what does get back ? number `5`, and then python will run `print(5)`.

Answer (score 8):

When you call `t.__str__()` directly it is just like any other method. The method  `__str__` method was overwritten, so there is nothing special about it when calling it directly.

When doing `print(t)` invocation happens internally, where some typechecking takes place

```
if (!PyUnicode_Check(res)) {
    _PyErr_Format(tstate, PyExc_TypeError,
                  "__str__ returned non-string (type %.200s)",
                  Py_TYPE(res)->tp_name);
    Py_DECREF(res);
    return NULL;
```

The [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__str__) states:

> The return value must be a string object.

so you should do something like

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(5)
```

or better, something more meaningful like

```
def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "TestObject with id: {}".format(self.id)
```

(The return type can be added to the function decalaration
so your editor will let you know if it doesn't have the right type.)

Comment: The method itself doesn't raise an error; it does return an int. It's the `str` function that raises an error if the `__str__` method returns a non-string.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `print(t)`, print function tries to get the `str(t)` value which returns integer. The value has to be **str**, so it raises an exception. But when you call `print(t.__str__())`, it doesn't raise an exception because the method acts like an ordinary method and the return value type doesn't have to be **str**.

Answer (score 0):

I will put here some finding that I found while looking at the behaviour of the `print` function. So, here goes nothing.

> Why didn't print(t.**str**()) want the the string type conversion?

It actually does (but, I think not the way you expect it). As most people have noted here, what happened with the code, is that it will evaluate the `__str__` function first (so, you got the number `5` here). And, what happened is that, it does the conversion (if you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1964)) using the `__str__` of `int` class (so, your number `5` will be printed as `"5"`)

> But, when I tried print(t) it threw the error TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type int).

This happen because there is a checking to ensure the object "representated" as string properly. This behaviour can be checked on this [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/object.c#L505)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you are correct in this part:

> As I understand print(t) is also calling the **str**(self) method.

Inside Python internal, when calling the `__str__` method, Python does call the method `__str__(self)`, **but only one time, and it does get the result, a number `5`**:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Objects/object.c#L499

But then, Python will check the result in C level, reports an error if the result is not a string:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Objects/object.c#L505

It will not try to call `__str__` method on the result again. So instead see the result, you will get the error `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)`.