# getting an error = TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer . I am learning methods in python and I am having this problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

what is the problem here pls help. What am I doing wrong here

```
class Name:

    def __init__(self,first,last):

      self.first = first
      self.last = last


    def __len__(self):
      return self.first

name_1 = Name('FIrst','last')

print(len(name_1))
```

Comment: If you want to get length of `'First'`, `__len__` should read `return len(self.first)`?

Comment: ohh thanks error fixed. Can we not get first from __len__() or is that not possible anyway thanks

Comment: I don't get what you mean by `not get first from __len__()`.

Comment: like in a normal method you can just return self.first    but you cant do the same in len I know its a silly question but I am really confused

Comment: `__len__` should return an integer. As long as you use `__len__`, no. Use other methods that does not have such requirements ;)

Comment: so if I say return 1 + 1 in __len __() would it work

Comment: thanks for your help I really understood it now

Comment: `return 1 + 1` will work. But does that usuful? `return  len(self.rist) + len(self.last)` ?

Comment: In plain English, what is supposed to be the rule that tells you how long (`__len__`) a `Name` is?

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481421/difference-between-len-and-len