# Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python

Tags: python, operators, increment, decrement

How do I use pre-increment/decrement operators (`++`, `--`), just like in C++?

Why does `++count` run, but not change the value of the variable?

Comment: Chris: You have answered my query (the what). In addition, I would like to know why Python differs in this behavior from C/C++.

Comment: Python is not C or C++. Different design decisions went into making the language.  In particular, Python deliberately does not define assignment operators that can be used in an arbitrary expression; rather, there are assignment statements and augmented assignment statements.  See reference below.

Comment: Kaizer: Coming from C/C++, I write ++count and it compiles in Python. So, I thought the language has the operators.

Comment: I believe that ++ exists in C mainly because it's syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic, e.g. the classic `while (dest++ = src++) {;}`.

Comment: given that most contemporary OOP languages had these symbols when GVR came up with Python, wouldn't it make sense to include a syntax warning for this construct?

Comment: @mehaase ++ and -- don't exist in c "as syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic", they exist because many processors have automatic increment and decrement memory access mechanisms (in general pointer indexing, stack indexing) as part of their native instruction set. For instance, in 6809 assembler: `sta x++` ...the atomic instruction that results stores the `a` accumulator where `x` is pointing, then increments `x` by the size of the accumulator. This is done because it is faster than pointer arithmetic, because it is very common, and because it's easy to understand. Both pre- and -post.

Comment: @fyngyrz for x86 there are actually instructions for increment and decrement and that is why (*and how C interprets*) `++` and `--` exist in C, it's not just *"syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic"*. `i++` and `i += 1` are not the same. Check [inc](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_140.html) and [dec](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_71.html) x86 instructions.

Comment: @christos-lytras - that's pretty much exactly what I said. You're responding to the wrong person.

Comment: @christos-lytras - _also_ - x++ --y, etc. long, _long_ predate the x86 instruction set. For instance, the 6809 had an awesome set of auto-inc and auto-dec indexing/stackop modes as well as inc, dec, add, subtract and so on.

Comment: @fyngyrz yes, it always depends on the compiler and for what instruction set (*assembler, processor architecture*) is build for. If it doesn't have any kind of increment instruction then it will use the addition instructions. Languages are agnostic when it comes to how the compilers *translate* the code.

Comment: Have you tried `+count`, `---count` and `+-+-+count`? These also "compile", but what are they supposed to do?

Answer (score 1330, accepted):

`++` is not an operator. It is two `+` operators. The `+` operator is the **identity** operator, which does nothing. (Clarification: the `+` and `-` unary operators only work on numbers, but I presume that you wouldn't expect a hypothetical `++` operator to work on strings.)

```
++count
```

Parses as

```
+(+count)
```

Which translates to

```
count
```

You have to use the slightly longer `+=` operator to do what you want to do:

```
count += 1
```

I suspect the `++` and `--` operators were left out for consistency and simplicity. I don't know the exact argument Guido van Rossum gave for the decision, but I can imagine a few arguments:

- Simpler parsing. Technically, parsing `++count` is ambiguous, as it could be `+`, `+`, `count` (two unary `+` operators) just as easily as it could be `++`, `count` (one unary `++` operator). It's not a significant syntactic ambiguity, but it does exist.
- Simpler language. `++` is nothing more than a synonym for `+= 1`. It was a shorthand invented because C compilers were stupid and didn't know how to optimize `a += 1` into the `inc` instruction most computers have. In this day of optimizing compilers and bytecode interpreted languages, adding operators to a language to allow programmers to optimize their code is usually frowned upon, especially in a language like Python that is designed to be consistent and readable.
- Confusing side-effects. One common newbie error in languages with `++` operators is mixing up the differences (both in precedence and in return value) between the pre- and post-increment/decrement operators, and Python likes to eliminate language "gotcha"-s. The [precedence issues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of [pre-/post-increment in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819123/1449799) are pretty hairy, and incredibly easy to mess up.

Comment: "The + operator is the "identity" operator, which does nothing." Only for numeric types; for other type it is an error by default.

Comment: Right. But then again, `++` and `--` should only be expected to work on numeric types.

Comment: Also, be aware that, in Python, += and friends are not operators that can be used in expressions.  Rather, in Python they are defined as part of an "augmented assignment statement".  This is consistent with the language design decision in Python to not allow assignment ("=") as an operator within arbitrary expressions, unlike what one can do in C. See http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Comment: The unary `+` operator has a use. For decimal.Decimal objects, it rounds to current precision.

Comment: Kaizer, that is an odd use for +. Any idea why Python does that for decimal.Decimal objects?

Comment: Chris, thanks so much for this detailed answer! I learnt a lot just by reading and understanding your explanation :-)

Comment: I'm betting on parser simplification. Note an item in [PEP 3099](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3099/), "Things that will Not Change in Python 3000": "The parser won't be more complex than LL(1). Simple is better than complex. This idea extends to the parser. Restricting Python's grammar to an LL(1) parser is a blessing, not a curse. It puts us in handcuffs that prevent us from going overboard and ending up with funky grammar rules like some other dynamic languages that will go unnamed, such as Perl." I don't see how to disambiguate `+ +` and `++` without breaking LL(1).

Comment: This must be _the_ reference question that all other "why doesn't Python have `++` operators?" questions get closed as duplicates of, because this answer accounts for 4% of my reputation.

Comment: This answer is correct so +1 but this is just another one of those annoyances with Python that have made me come to really dislike it. `strip()` instead of `trim()` like every other languages, no switches, some OO functions and some not ([`len(s)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/237150/156755) vs [`s.lower()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6797990/156755)). Very frustrating and inconsistent language

Comment: For anyone who was, like me, at a loss as to what the purpose of the unary + operator is, it's the opposite of the unary - operator. What is -1? It's negative one. What is +1? It's positive one. What is +(+1)? It's still positive one.  Feel stupid for having wondered now? Me too.

Comment: @Basic the beauty of python's built-in functions, such as `len()`, is they usually map to a method in the object, allowing you to override or give power to the built-in's for any of your own classes -- `s.__len__()` in this case.

Comment: @CivFan Why is that any more desirable than inheriting from an object that has a length method/property that can be overridden? As far as I can see, it simply adds a layer of indirection for no tangible benefit

Comment: @Basic But.. that's precisely what's happening. This leads into something else beautiful about python, a public, private, protected method scheme enforced by consistent coding style, rather than strictly enforced. `s.__len__()` is there when you really want to override it, but hidden away not cluttering the vast majority of classes that have no need for it.

Comment: @CivFan then a) `__len__()` isn't really private, it's just public but called via indiretion and b) we now need to know all the global methods that call the private methods when the object could've just had a `length()` method which could be overriden if desired.

Comment: @Basic precisely on both accounts! `__len__()` is not really private, but looks like it when you don't need it, and only there when you need it. When you introspect an object for useful methods, you don't end up finding an undefined `length()` and a hundred other undefined built-in methods. But that one time you do, it's still there under the covers. I need a drink. ;)

Comment: @CivFan I think we'll have to agree to disagree, I still think it looks like noise and breaks OO principles for little benefit, if any. For all that, I need a drink too. Have a nice weekend

Comment: 'Python likes to eliminate language "gotcha"-s' - isn't this a language gotcha?

Comment: how to increment/decrement a recordset ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081083/how-to-increment-or-decrement-a-recordset-odoo9)

Comment: It's not correct to say that `++` is nothing more than a synonym for `+= 1`. There are pre-increment and post-increment variants of ++ so it is clearly not the same thing. I agree with the rest of your points, though.

Comment: Just for this, your are my idol: "C compilers were stupid and didn't know how to optimize a += 1"

Comment: Each to their own.  I use ++ and -- all the time and don't end up messing anything up.  Python is an OK language, but it has many flaws and I find the community over religious about various language constructs.  Its a tool, not the Mona Lisa.  Lets get the job done and move on to the next task ... which will most probably be written in R, or Matlab or C++

Comment: To future-proof @NedDeily's highly up-voted remark on assignments, Python 3.8 allows assignment nearly anywhere with the new `:=` operator.

Comment: "why does Python even have this unary operator? It exists only to complement the – operator if you need to overload these operators for your own classes. (See the documentation for the __pos__ special method.)" From: https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2018/05/21/pythons-fake-increment-and-decrement-operators/

Answer (score 450):

Python does not have pre and post increment operators.

In Python, integers are **immutable**. That is you can't change them. This is because the integer objects can be used under several names. Try this:

```
>>> b = 5
>>> a = 5
>>> id(a)
162334512
>>> id(b)
162334512
>>> a is b
True
```

a and b above are actually the same object. If you incremented a, you would also increment b. That's not what you want. So you have to reassign. Like this:

```
b = b + 1
```

Many C programmers who used python wanted an increment operator, but that operator would look like it incremented the object, while it actually reassigns it. Therefore the `-=` and `+=` operators where added, to be shorter than the `b = b + 1`, while being clearer and more flexible than `b++`, so most people will increment with:

```
b += 1
```

Which will reassign `b` to `b+1`. That is not an increment operator, because it does not increment `b`, it reassigns it.

In short: Python behaves differently here, because it is not C, and is not a low level wrapper around machine code, but a high-level dynamic language, where increments don't make sense, and also are not as necessary as in C, where you use them every time you have a loop, for example.

Comment: That example is wrong (and you're probably confusing immutability with identity) - they have the same id due to some vm optimization that uses the same objects for numbers till 255 (or something like that). Eg (bigger numbers):

    >>> a = 1231231231231
    >>> b = 1231231231231
    >>> id(a), id(b)
    (32171144, 32171168)

Comment: The immutability claim is spurious. Conceptually, `i++` would mean to assign `i + 1` to the *variable* `i`. `i = 5; i++` means to assign `6` to `i`, not modify the `int` object pointed to by `i`. That is, it does not mean to [increment the value of `5`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SufficientlyLarge.html)!

Comment: @Mechanical snail: In which case it would not be increment operators at all. And then the += operator is clearer, more explicit, more flexible and does the same thing anyway.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: In C++ and Java, `i++` only operates on lvalues. If it were intended to increment the object pointed to by `i`, this restriction would be unnecessary.

Comment: Immutability is indeed irrelevant in this case.  Consider:  Clojure has a built-in increment operator and all data structures are immutable by default.  While it's true you get a new reference to the new value, that's mostly orthogonal to the purely syntactic choice of `++` vs. `+= 1`.

Comment: let us [keep any further repetition of the same old arguments in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36452/discussion-between-lennart-regebro-and-tarik)

Comment: **Moderator note:** Comments are not for extended discussion. Please use chat for that.

Comment: Please read [this reply why Guido didn't define `++` operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3654936/548792). Deliberating on the **immutability** of built-in types is irrelevant, while the post misses the point of `++` being an _expression_ while `+=1` is a _statement_.

Answer (score 60):

While the others answers are correct in so far as they show what a mere `+` usually does (namely, leave the number as it is, if it is one), they are incomplete in so far as they don't explain what happens.

To be exact, `+x` evaluates to `x.__pos__()` and `++x` to `x.__pos__().__pos__()`.

I could imagine a VERY weird class structure (Children, don't do this at home!) like this:

```py
class ValueKeeper(object):
    def __init__(self, value): self.value = value
    def __str__(self): return str(self.value)

class A(ValueKeeper):
    def __pos__(self):
        print('called A.__pos__')
        return B(self.value - 3)

class B(ValueKeeper):
    def __pos__(self):
        print('called B.__pos__')
        return A(self.value + 19)

x = A(430)
print(x, type(x))
print(+x, type(+x))
print(++x, type(++x))
print(+++x, type(+++x))
```

Answer (score 25):

### TL;DR

Python does not have unary increment/decrement operators (`--`/`++`). Instead, to increment a value, use

```
a += 1
```

### More detail and gotchas

But be careful here. If you're coming from C, even this is different in python. Python doesn't have "variables" in the sense that C does, instead python uses *names* and *objects*, and in python `int`s are immutable.

so lets say you do

```
a = 1
```

What this means in python is: create an object of type `int` having value `1` and bind the name `a` to it. The *object* is an instance of `int` having value `1`, and the *name* `a` refers to it. The name `a` and the object to which it refers are distinct.

Now lets say you do

```
a += 1
```

Since `int`s are immutable, what happens here is as follows:

1. look up the object that `a` refers to (it is an `int` with id `0x559239eeb380`)
2. look up the value of object `0x559239eeb380` (it is `1`)
3. add 1 to that value (1 + 1 = 2)
4. create a **new** `int` object with value `2` (it has object id `0x559239eeb3a0`)
5. rebind the name `a` to this new object
6. Now `a` refers to object `0x559239eeb3a0` and the original object (`0x559239eeb380`) is no longer refered to by the name `a`. If there aren't any other names refering to the original object it will be garbage collected later.

Give it a try yourself:

```
a = 1
print(hex(id(a)))
a += 1
print(hex(id(a)))
```

Comment: apart from the fact that small integers are 'interned', so they will never be garbage collected.

Comment: What you're calling 'names' are commonly called variables (including by Mr Rossum) across programming languages. They may have different scope and lifetime and more relaxed typing rules in dynamic languages like Python (Lisp, JavaScript, Lua, etc.) As @TonySuffolk66 points out, they aren't actually always references to GC'able objects - and a C/C++ variable may hold a reference to an object, and as in Python, such an object may be shared between variables, and GC'd when there are no more references to it.

Comment: You are correct that Guido talks about variables, but when you look at any documentation that looks at the internal semantics you will see that the details talk about names bound to objects. 
It is a minor distinction for most developers but an important one when you start talking about the impact on objects of operations.

Answer (score 25):

In python 3.8+ you can do :

```
(a:=a+1) #same as ++a (increment, then return new value)
(a:=a+1)-1 #same as a++ (return the incremented value -1) (useless)
```

You can do a lot of thinks with this.

```
>>> a = 0
>>> while (a:=a+1) < 5:
    print(a)

    
1
2
3
4
```

Or if you want write somthing with more sophisticated syntaxe (the goal is not optimization):

```
>>> del a
>>> while (a := (a if 'a' in locals() else 0) + 1) < 5:
    print(a)

    
1
2
3
4
```

It will return 0 even if 'a' doesn't exist without errors, and then will set it to 1

Comment: Greate answer! Just one suggestion: `a++` would increment but return the old value, `(a:=a+1)` is more like an `++a` that would increment and return the new value.

Comment: But can you do `(a:+=1)`?

Comment: @ingyhere no, it's an syntax error because '+=' is an operation between 2 object (__iadd__), you can't assigne an syntaxe operation to an variable

Answer (score 15):

Python does not have these operators, but if you really need them you can write a function having the same functionality.

```
def PreIncrement(name, local={}):
    #Equivalent to ++name
    if name in local:
        local[name]+=1
        return local[name]
    globals()[name]+=1
    return globals()[name]

def PostIncrement(name, local={}):
    #Equivalent to name++
    if name in local:
        local[name]+=1
        return local[name]-1
    globals()[name]+=1
    return globals()[name]-1
```

Usage:

```
x = 1
y = PreIncrement('x') #y and x are both 2
a = 1
b = PostIncrement('a') #b is 1 and a is 2
```

Inside a function you have to add locals() as a second argument if you want to change local variable, otherwise it will try to change global.

```
x = 1
def test():
    x = 10
    y = PreIncrement('x') #y will be 2, local x will be still 10 and global x will be changed to 2
    z = PreIncrement('x', locals()) #z will be 11, local x will be 11 and global x will be unaltered
test()
```

Also with these functions you can do:

```
x = 1
print(PreIncrement('x'))   #print(x+=1) is illegal!
```

But in my opinion following approach is much clearer:

```
x = 1
x+=1
print(x)
```

Decrement operators:

```
def PreDecrement(name, local={}):
    #Equivalent to --name
    if name in local:
        local[name]-=1
        return local[name]
    globals()[name]-=1
    return globals()[name]

def PostDecrement(name, local={}):
    #Equivalent to name--
    if name in local:
        local[name]-=1
        return local[name]+1
    globals()[name]-=1
    return globals()[name]+1
```

I used these functions in my module translating javascript to python.

Comment: Note: while great, these helper methods will not work if your locals exist on class function stack frame. i.e - calling them from within a class method def will not work - the 'locals()' dict is a snapshot, and does not update the stack frame.

Answer (score 12):

> In Python, a distinction between expressions and statements is rigidly
>   enforced, in contrast to languages such as Common Lisp, Scheme, or
>   Ruby.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Expressions)

So by introducing such operators, you would break the expression/statement split.

For the same reason you can't write

```
if x = 0:
  y = 1
```

as you can in some other languages where such distinction is not preserved.

Comment: Interestingly, this restriction will be lifted in the upcoming release Python 3.8 with the new syntax for Assignment expressions (PEP-572 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/). We will be able to write `if (n := len(a)) > 10:  y = n + 1` for example. Note that the distinction is clear because of the introduction of a new operator for that purpose (`:=`)

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, I missed ++ and -- functionality as well. A few million lines of c code engrained that kind of thinking in my old head, and rather than fight it... Here's a class I cobbled up that implements:

```
pre- and post-increment, pre- and post-decrement, addition,
subtraction, multiplication, division, results assignable
as integer, printable, settable.
```

Here 'tis:

```
class counter(object):
    def __init__(self,v=0):
        self.set(v)

    def preinc(self):
        self.v += 1
        return self.v
    def predec(self):
        self.v -= 1
        return self.v

    def postinc(self):
        self.v += 1
        return self.v - 1
    def postdec(self):
        self.v -= 1
        return self.v + 1

    def __add__(self,addend):
        return self.v + addend
    def __sub__(self,subtrahend):
        return self.v - subtrahend
    def __mul__(self,multiplier):
        return self.v * multiplier
    def __div__(self,divisor):
        return self.v / divisor

    def __getitem__(self):
        return self.v

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.v)

    def set(self,v):
        if type(v) != int:
            v = 0
        self.v = v
```

You might use it like this:

```
c = counter()                          # defaults to zero
for listItem in myList:                # imaginary task
     doSomething(c.postinc(),listItem) # passes c, but becomes c+1
```

...already having c, you could do this...

```
c.set(11)
while c.predec() > 0:
    print c
```

....or just...

```
d = counter(11)
while d.predec() > 0:
    print d
```

...and for (re-)assignment into integer...

```
c = counter(100)
d = c + 223 # assignment as integer
c = c + 223 # re-assignment as integer
print type(c),c # <type 'int'> 323
```

...while this will maintain c as type counter:

```
c = counter(100)
c.set(c + 223)
print type(c),c # <class '__main__.counter'> 323
```

EDIT:

**And then there's this bit of unexpected (and thoroughly unwanted) behavior**,

```
c = counter(42)
s = '%s: %d' % ('Expecting 42',c) # but getting non-numeric exception
print s
```

...because inside that tuple, **getitem**() isn't what used, instead a reference to the object is passed to the formatting function. Sigh. So:

```
c = counter(42)
s = '%s: %d' % ('Expecting 42',c.v) # and getting 42.
print s
```

...or, more verbosely, and explicitly what we actually wanted to happen, although counter-indicated in actual form by the verbosity (use `c.v` instead)...

```
c = counter(42)
s = '%s: %d' % ('Expecting 42',c.__getitem__()) # and getting 42.
print s
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no post/pre increment/decrement operators in python like in languages like C.

We can see `++` or `--` as multiple signs getting multiplied, like we do in maths (-1) * (-1) = (+1).

E.g.

```
---count
```

Parses as

```
-(-(-count)))
```

Which translates to

```
-(+count)
```

Because, multiplication of `-` sign with `-` sign is `+`

And finally,

```
-count
```

Comment: What does this say that other answers don't?

Comment: @DanielB. Other answers haven't told what happens internally. And, neither they have told what will happen when you will write `-----count`.

Comment: There isn't any mention that multiplication is being carried out, so I thought a consice and to the point answer would be useful for fellow users. No offense if you understood from that.        Learning is more important than the source where you learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Henry's answer, I experimentally implemented a syntax sugar library realizing `a++`: [hdytto](https://github.com/TRSasasusu/hdytto).

The usage is simple. After installing from PyPI, place `sitecustomize.py`:

```py
from hdytto import register_hdytto
register_hdytto()
```

in your project directory. Then, make `main.py`:

```
# coding: hdytto

a = 5
print(a++)
print(++a)
b = 10 - --a
print(b--)
```

and run it by `PYTHONPATH=. python main.py`. The output will be

```
5
7
4
```

hdytto replaces `a++` as `((a:=a+1)-1)` when decoding the script file, so it works.

Comment: Using tricks to change the syntax of a language is exactly the kind of things you shouldn't do, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

A straight forward workaround

```
c = 0
c = (lambda c_plusplus: plusplus+1)(c)
print(c)
1
```

No more typing

```
 c = c + 1
```

Also, you could just write
c++
and finish all your code and then do search/replace for "c++", replace with "c=c+1". Just make sure regular expression search is off.

Comment: -1, the lambda workaround works just once - it always return 1. And the search&replace also doesn't work for all cases - consider `if (c++): ...`