# Python integer incrementing with ++

Tags: python, syntax, increment

I've always laughed to myself when I've looked back at my VB6 days and thought, "What modern language doesn't allow incrementing with double plus signs?":

```
number++
```

To my surprise, I can't find anything about this in the Python docs. Must I really subject myself to `number = number + 1`? Don't people use the `++` / `--` notation?

Comment: I for one am quite happy that we don't have to put up with things like `a[i] = i++;` where the order of evaluation in C++ is undefined.

Comment: Even if there's such a thing, I think in Python the order is well-defined. (http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)

Comment: Answers to your questions in the given order: “Erlang, Python, Lua etc” (for "modern" meaning after the creation of C); “No”; and “Not necessarily”.

Comment: Are you talking about prefix `++` or postfix `++`?  I, for one, hated teaching this part of the C language, and avoided it because of the ambiguities.  Why look for this horrible thing in other languages?

Comment: Indeed, why to have the shortcuts for pervasive task?

Comment: Disagree with y'all: `i++` is less to write so less to read. Less to read means brain can focus more on the big picture.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: a better solution would be to well define the evaluation order, probably from left to right, rather than dropping a useful operator. And to the OP: Python is hardly a modern language... and is a quite crappy language actually, despite being widely used.

Comment: @Robino Less to read, more to process. What's more complex and ugly, `i++` or `i += 1`?

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Neither is particularly complex and neither is ugly. The first one is quicker to understand.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Python is hardly a crappy or archaic language. It has a fairly unique syntax and is easy to learn. If by crappy you mean slow because it is interpreted rather than compiled, pyc is actually very quick.

Comment: ++i vs i++, then let's talk about "brain can focus on other things" again, @Robino.

Comment: Learning python myself now (C# background) and I find this annoying. I would say it is smarter to just implement it and let the programmer choose how they want to write their syntax. Frankly there is nothing ambiguous or hard to understand about i++. The people using ++i without understanding what it does - that's their fault. I just don't think taking away such a common statement is fair though, but whatever it is what it is.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard `++i` = i is incremented then returned. `i++` = i is returned then incremented. Seems pretty simple to me... Yes, a brand new person who has never seen it before might not know that, but it doesn't take much to figure it out (a simple Google/SO search), and the flexibility provided is quite handy in some situations. I am less liberal with `i++` than some (I don't usually use things like `result = array[i++]` for example). @others I do agree it is quicker to see what is going on than with `i += 1`. There is less for my brain to parse and it just 'clicks' as soon as I see it.

Comment: What's even more amazing is that in 2022 they still did not add '++' to the language :-( As for readability, if you are not used to '++' it is obviously less readable than x += 1 (like for some people not used to the ternary operator, it's an "awful feature"...)

Comment: is there a reason for still not having `++` in python?

Comment: even worse: ++i is not an error but probably just an unused expression as a+1 or -a. caused me a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1746, accepted):

Python doesn't support `++`, but you can do:

```
number += 1
```

Comment: I think that @Thomas's explanation is more useful here; I think the question is more of `why` and not `what`.

Comment: Agreed with @rickcnagy, more like the "how to do it?" (if you really don't care about brevity of code you could also simply do number = number + 1) the reasoning on why ++ and -- don't exist in Python seems more useful.

Comment: Not exactly. The following will not work as expected: `progress = 0; print(progress += 1)`. So `+=` does not seem to completely replace C++'s `++` operator.

Comment: Python has loads of ?= where ? is replaced by another operator, although it wont work with every operator. For example n \= 2 becomes n = n \ 2, however n +== 1 doesn't unpack to n = n += 1

Answer (score 538):

Simply put, the `++` and `--` operators don't exist in Python because they wouldn't be *operators*, they would have to be *statements*. All namespace modification in Python is a statement, for simplicity and consistency. That's one of the design decisions. And because integers are immutable, the only way to 'change' a variable is by reassigning it.

Fortunately we have wonderful tools for the use-cases of `++` and `--` in other languages, like `enumerate()` and `itertools.count()`.

Comment: useful reference to `enumerate()` and `itertools.count()`

Comment: Care to suggest an elegant replacement for this: `reserved_index = 0; col_names = [name if name != '_' else 'reserved' + (reserved_index++) for name in column_names]`?  I'm passed a list of column names where some that are not interesting are just `'_'`.  I need to construct a temporary table with those `'_'`s replaced with unique but non-meaningful names.  The in-place postincrement operator would make this easy; I'm struggling to come up with something else that doesn't involve looping over the array explicitly.

Comment: @Tom `reserved_indices = itertools.count(); col_names = [name if name != '_' else 'reserved' + str(next(reserved_indices)) for name in column_names]`

Comment: This decision violates the rule - no surprise. ++number works in most of languages. - How many bugs this may cause. The language should be also developer friendly )

Comment: @jeffery.yuan Been at it less than a year (meaning python--I've coded for a couple decades plus), but, man, the number of things like that...boggles the mind.  Lowest common denominator kinda won.

Comment: PEP 572 changed much of this.

Comment: [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572) currently changes nothing for most of us, because assignment expressions are only available under Python 3.8. Meanwhile, Python 3.5 through 3.7 have yet hit to EOL. If you'd like your code to remain compatible with actively maintained Python versions (and you should), just use the [long-standing `itertools.count()` iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), which has existed since *literally the dawn of time, space, and Python 3 itself,* is trivial to use, and comes with no such portability concerns.

Comment: are = you[kidding++] << me;   are = you[plus(kidding)] <<me;

Answer (score 66):

You can do:

```
number += 1
```

Answer (score 38):

Yes. The `++` operator is not available in Python. Guido doesn't like these operators.

Comment: It makes writing UI code so much less line-y though.  Well other than the fact that using Python cuts your lines to like 15% what they'd be in C++, heh.

Comment: `--Guido`......

Answer (score 26):

The main reason ++ comes in handy in C-like languages is for keeping track of indices. In Python, you deal with data in an abstract way and seldom increment through indices and such. The closest-in-spirit thing to `++` is the `next` method of iterators.

Comment: Sometimes I find that you really do just need iteration indexes, e.g., if you want to track how many times a function runs before it converges, etc. Though maybe that still counts as "seldom used", Python is pretty well suited for the most part to scientific coding, FWIW.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/python-behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators) for an explanation of why this doesn't work.

Python doesn't really have ++ and --, and I personally never felt it was such a loss.

I prefer functions with clear names to operators with non-always clear semantics (hence the classic interview question about ++x vs. x++ and the difficulties of overloading it). I've also never been a huge fan of what post-incrementation does for readability.

You could always define some wrapper class (like accumulator) with clear increment semantics, and then do something like x.increment() or x.incrementAndReturnPrev()

Answer (score 9):

Here there is an explanation:
http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/444733-why-there-no-post-pre-increment-operator-python

However the absence of this operator is in the python philosophy increases consistency and avoids implicitness.

In addition, this kind of increments are not widely used in python code because python have a strong implementation of the iterator pattern plus the function enumerate.