# Does Python support ++?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python)

I'm new to Python, I'm confused about ++ python. I've tried to ++num but num's value is not changed:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> ++a
1
>>> print a
1
>>> print(++a)
1
```

Could somebody explain this? If Python support ++, why num has not changed. If it doesn't why can I use ++?

Comment: `++a` means `+(+(a))`

Comment: @poke Thanks! I've not searched that question, sorry to asked a duplicated question, should I choose an answer or delete this qeustion?

Comment: This topic has been already discussed [Python integer incrementing with ++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632677/python-integer-incrementing-with)

Comment: @sunkehappy The question will be closed soon with a link to the other question, so don’t worry about it.

Comment: @gefei I don't understand how that's valid syntax - explanation please?

Answer (score 13):

No:

```
In [1]: a=1

In [2]: a++
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     a++
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But you can:

```
In [3]: a+=1

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 2
```

Comment: " There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch. " as stated in the [Zen of Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python)

Answer (score 1):

It should look like

```
a = 6
a += 1
print a
>>> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be one and preferably only one obvious way to do it

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a += 1
>>> a
2
```