# Python 3.4 while loop increment

Tags: python, while-loop, increment

```
  x = Flase
  while !x :
     a = 0
     print(a)
     a++
     pass
     if a == 10:
       x = True
    else:
       continue
```

I get an error at "a++". I a using visual studio 2013 community and it gives me a red underline after "a++" and just before "pass"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python integer incrementing with ++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632677/python-integer-incrementing-with)

Comment: Please check your spelling before asking questions. a++ is an invalid python syntax. Use a += 1 instead. !x is an invalid python syntax as well. Use not x instead. Remember python is not Java or C#.

Comment: simply use a += 1

Answer (score 2):

Python does not support ++. you can do this

```
     a = a + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax like  `++` or `--`  in Python, but you can do `+= 1` and `-= 1`.

And there are some logical error in your program

```
x = False
a = 0  # a should be initialized here. If it is initialized in loop it will be a never-ending loop
while not x :

   print(a)
   a+=1
   if a == 10:
     x = True
   else:
     continue
```

**Notes:**

1. check the spelling on `False` you have written it wrong
2. there is no need for `pass`
3. instead of using `!` you should use `not` in Python

**A simpler and more pythonic way is to use `for` and `range`:**

```
for a in range(10):
    print(a)
```