# Count the number of times something occurs in a csv column

Tags: csv, for-loop, arcpy

I would like to search a csv column and have my script return the total number of times each cell phone is used... Here is my code, but I am not sure what the problem is...

```
import arcpy
fc = "C:\Script\SAMPLES\SAMPLES.csv"
field = "phone"
iPhone = 0
Android = 0
other = 0
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    #print(row.getValue(field))
    if row.getValue(field)=='iPhone':
        iPhone = iPhone + str(iPhone)
        print "The number of iPhones: " + iPhone
    elif:    
        Android=Android + str(Android)
        print "The number of Androids: " + Android
    elif:
        other=other + str(other)
        print "The number of other: " + other
```

I've also included the error I am receiving.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-    packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Script\searchcursor.py", line 11, in <module>
    iPhone = iPhone + str(iPhone)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

This indicates that you're (essentially) trying to add a number and letter together. Python sees `0` (an integer) and `'0'` (a string) as different, and can't add them together. Since you are using `iPhone` (and `Android` and `other`) as counters, you will want to add two integers together.

---

I'm also not clear on what you're trying to add to that counter, though.

```
iPhone = iPhone + int(iPhone)
```

If `iPhone = 0`, then that formula is `iPhone = 0 + 0`. If you'd already counted 2 iPhones, that formula is `iPhone = 2 + 2` -- you're doubling the value rather than incrementing.

You probably just want:

```
iPhone = iPhone + 1
```

or ([shorter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2632687/2118067))

```
iPhone += 1
```