# How to increment a value in postgres with an update query (python)

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, sql-update

I'd like to run a one-line update query (using Python and Postgres) that increments a value by 1. **Whats the most efficient way to do that?** I thought that ideally it would look like this (in my Django Views.py file):

```
def login_user(request):
    UserProfile.objects.filter(username=username).update(logins += 1)
```

BUT because of the ' += ', that code gives me this `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` - which is odd because I thought += was legitimate python ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632677/python-integer-incrementing-with)). Surely there is a more efficient way to increment a value in postgres than this (which does work):

```
def login_user(request):
    thing = UserProfile.objects.filter(username=username).values("logins")   # gets the initial value
    total_logins = int(thing[0]['logins'])+1   # adds 1 to that value
    UserProfile.objects.filter(username=username).update(logins = total_logins)   # Updates the value in the database
```

*I have found similar solutions on StackOverflow but their answers gave SQL queries instead of python queries.*  - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/) function.

```
def login_user(request):
    thing = UserProfile.objects.get(username=username)  # gets the initial value
    thing.login = F('login') + 1   # adds 1 to that value
    thing.save()
```

or

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(username=username).update(logins=F('login')+1)
```

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thanks for linking to the docs for F().  So basically, it looks like ' += ' does not work as I originally wrote it because it's trying to increment an Object instead of a Value, whereas the F() function essentially, just pulls the value of the 'logins' field.   +1 for a speedy answer!