# in python, ++x is correct syntax. What does "++x" mean?

Tags: python, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Behaviour of increment and decrement operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/python-behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators)

```
>>> a=2
>>> ++a
2
>>> a++
Traceback (  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    a++
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> ++a
2
```

why ++x is OK?

(I'm asking since someone at work habitually wrote ++i, which didn't do as (habitually) expected, but didn't throw an error either, so it took some time to find the bug.)

Comment: http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means `+(+a)`, i.e. opposite to the meaning of `-(-a)` (although obviously in this case, the result is the same!)

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex.

Comment: `+(+a)` actually is not the opposite of `-(-a)`, it's the same :-)

Comment: hence it's possible to write ------------a and +++++++++++++++++a. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to `+(+a)`:

```
>>> +-2
-2
>>> -+2
-2
>>> --2
2
>>> ++++-2
-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Python: Behaviour of increment and decrement operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/python-behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators).

Although I cannot find documentation for the exact reasoning for the operator I'll quote a portion from the accepted answer in the linked question that I believe is the case:

> - Simpler language. ++ is nothing more than a synonym for += 1. It was    a shorthand invented because C compilers were stupid and didn't
>     know    how to optimize a += 1 into the inc instruction most computers
>     have.    In this day of optimizing compilers and bytecode interpreted 
>     languages, adding operators to a language to allow programmers to
>     optimize their code is usually frowned upon, especially in a language 
>     like Python that is designed to be consistent and readable.