# C++ vs Python implementation

Tags: python, c++, loops

My C++ is functioning as expected but the equivalent Python code hangs in an infinite loop. Help!

## C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;++i){

        int j=0;

        while(i!=j){
            ++j;
            cout<<j<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

## Python

```
for i in range(4):

    j = 0

    while i != j:

        ++j

        print(j)
```

Comment: Please don't get into the habit of doing line-by-line translations from one language like C++ to another, and vice-versa.  Learn the language as if the other language doesn't exist.

Comment: Paul has a point ... or many ...what is the purpose of the loop?

Comment: Well, I did try += as well but it didn't work in the original implementation for some reason. At least now I know why python doesn't use increment operator haha.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Why are there no ++ and --​ operators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3654830/995714), [Python integer incrementing with ++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2632677/995714), [in python, ++x is correct syntax. What does "++x" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11209899/995714), [Does Python support ++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13229760/995714), [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1485841/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`++j` is not a thing in Python.  You want `j += 1`.

Comment: I wasted too much time on this...

Comment: @TejasPandey why don't you read the interpreter error? Googling for things like `python "++" syntax error` would give you a lot of answers immediately: [Python integer incrementing with ++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2632677/995714), [in python, ++x is correct syntax. What does "++x" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11209899/995714), [Does Python support ++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13229760/995714)...

Comment: I got an infinite loop so no error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid ambiguity/confusion, our [Benevolent Dictator For Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum) thought to not allow `++` or `--` into the Python ecosystem. That means you are in an infinite loop because `++j` does not do what you believe it to do.

Comment: Well my understanding now is that all variables are immutable so you can't do ++. They are immutable because of how python handles datatypes.


`x = 5`
`x++` makes sense

`x = 'blah'`
`x++` doesn't make sense.