# how does python parse ++x?

Tags: python, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python)

Completely new to python I wrote ++x thinking it would increment x. So I was wrong about that, no problem. But no syntax error either. Hence my question: what does ++x actually mean in python?

Comment: you're probably looking for x += 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator is the [unary plus operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations); it returns its numeric argument unchanged.  So `++x` is parsed as `+(+(x))`, and gives `x` unchanged (as long as `x` contains a number):

```
>>> ++5
5
>>> ++"hello"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

If `+` is called on an object of a user-defined class, the [`__pos__` special method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pos__) will be called if it exists; otherwise, `TypeError` will be raised as above.

To confirm this we can use the [ast module](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) to show how Python parses the expression:

```
import ast
print(ast.dump(ast.parse('++x', mode='eval')))
Expression(body=UnaryOp(op=UAdd(), operand=UnaryOp(op=UAdd(), operand=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()))))
```

Comment: Thank you, really useful answer, particularly the tip about using the ast module. My immediate reaction to "it returns its numeric argument unchanged" was: so what's the point? But I guess people will find uses for it with user-defined classes.