# In python,what does ++ mean?

Tags: python

I read a script like that

```
for ... :
   for ...:
      ++i
```

but what does `++` mean?
Is `++` operator is python?

Comment: Where did you read that script? I think it may have been a joke or it wasn't actually Python

Comment: @jamylak: it may also have been a bug.

Comment: a very strange script .I am a new comer to python,but why python don't offer a convenient operator like count++,any reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python)

Answer (score 10):

In python, that's just unary plus twice. It doesn't do anything. A single one might coerce a bool to an int, but the second one is totally useless.

Comment: This is the best answer :)

Comment: +1 just for the `bool-to-int` point, which hadn't occurred to me at all.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> +1
1
>>> ++1
1
>>> +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++1
1
```

Comment: I think you forgot a `+` in the last line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `i+=1` instead of `i++` for your for loop. There is no `++` usage in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Python is an implicitly typed language, therefore, unless we know what type the variable has, we cannot tell for sure what happens if we apply an operator to it. In your example, `i` is not necessarily an integer, it can be an object with an overloaded unary + (`__pos__`), for example:

```
class Duplicator(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

    def __pos__(self):
        self.s += self.s
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return self.s

z = Duplicator("ha ")
# 1000 lines of code
print +z
print ++z
print +++z
```

So the answer to your question "what does `++x` mean in python" is "it depends on what `x` is".