# How to increment or decrement a recordset? odoo9

Tags: python, api, orm, odoo, odoo-9

My record set is  `items = product.pricelist.item(4,3,2)`

`qty_in_product_uom` is passed by the user( `4= min_quantity 500, 3= 250, 2= 100` )

```
for rule in items:
    if rule.min_quantity and qty_in_product_uom < rule.min_quantity:
        print inside rule.id
```

now i want such a function that selects the next id if the condition is true

eg. if user passes `qty_in_product_uom` say 110 then my above if condition will give `id=2` in this case i want `id=3`

if `id=3` then answer will be `id=4`

and if `id=4` select `id=4`

As recordsets are immutable how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recordset(`BaseModel` class) is an iterable Python object. That means you can use the object in almost the same way you use a list. For example:

`item = product.pricelist.item(4,3,2)[0]`

`print item # This will print product.pricelist.item(4,)`

If you want to get a record from the recordset using its id you can use:

`item = product.pricelist.item(4,3,2).index(3)`

`print item # This will print product.pricelist.item(3,)`

Comment: `TypeError: field 'id' cannot be assigned` How do i assign it to rule or rule.id

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which code gives you that error?

Comment: I am passing the `rule.id` to a method which passes the `id` which i want in `int`. so how do i assign it to the recordset ? `rule.id = _get_id(rule.id)` if i do it as `rule = _get_id(rule.id)` it makes `rule` as `int` i want `rule` as `product.pricelist.item(3,)` if my `_get_id(rule.id)` reutrns `int = 3`

Comment: The recordset is immutable. You cannot change it in any way. You can either get any of its objects in the way I showed you on the answer or create a new recordset.

Comment: if i `return items[self]` from the  `def _get_id(self)` then it returns the whole list. Then it gives me this error `ValueError: Expected singleton: product.pricelist.item(4, 3, 2)`

Comment: My bad i was returning `items` not `items[self]` :P now it returns the recordset.

Comment: Do you know a way where i can pass the `list id` to the `method`. ?For eg. I am passing the `rule.id` which passes the `id` from the database, is there any way where i can pass `rule[i]` where i would be the `list id`