# Is using two addition operators for adding two integers valid in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, operators

I've just started learning python. I was just trying to play with print function. I ended up writing the below code.

```
print(2 ++ 2)
```

I expected the Python interpreter to throw an error since I put two addition operators next to each other without putting an integer between them. Contrarily, the python interpreter did not throw any error and returned 4 as output.
I also tried the below code:-

```
print(4 -- 2)
```

The output was 6.

Could someone explain me these?

Comment: If you subtract minus two from something, that's the same thing as adding two to it.

Comment: Related (but probably not a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/1485841/5827958

Comment: @zondo: no, that's very much a suitable dupe target, the explanation is exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`2 ++ 2` is** interpreted as:

```
2 ++ 2 == 2 + (+2)
```

So you perform an addition between `2` and `+2` where the second `+` is thus an unary plus. The same happens if you write `2 +++ 2`:

```
2 +++ 2 == 2 + (+(+2))
```

For the `4 -- 2` case something similar happens:

```
4 -- 2 == 4 - (-2)
```

So you subtract `-2` from `4` resulting in `6`.

Using two, three (or even more) additions is not prohibited, but **for integers/floats** it only results in more confusion, so you better do not do this.

There are `class`es  that **define their own unary plus and unary minus** operator (like `Counter` for instance). In that case `++` can have a different behaviour than `+`. So you **better do not use `++`** (and if you do, put a space between the two `+`ses to make it explicit that the second `+` is a different operator).

Since there are unary plus and minus operators, anything after the first `+` or `-` is interpreted as unary. So `2 ++--++- 2` will result in `0` since:

```
2 ++--++- 2 == 2 + (+(-(-(+(+(-2))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
2 ++ 2
```

is

```
2 + (+2)
```

and

```
4 -- 2
```

is

```
4 - (-2)
```

It's just a question of operator precedence, fixity, and arity:

```
2 ==+-+-+ 2
#>>> True
```

Note that for numbers, unary prefix `+` is defined as the identity function, and unary prefix `-` is defined as negation (which means that a double unary prefix `--` is the identity function); but Python supports operator overloading, so there is no guarantee that this is true for all objects.