# Getting values for matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I'm new to python and I tried to store integer values in a 2 dimensional list using loops(I use this logic in C for getting input for matrix). When I run this code, it shows **IndexError: list assignment index out of range**. What caused this error?
Code to print numbers from 1-9 in matrix form:

```
num=1
a=[[]]
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        a[i][j]=num
        ++num
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        print(a[i][j]+" ")
    print("\n")
```

Comment: You create an empty array and then write into it. You need to use append(), or create the array with the initial size.  But really look at the "numpy" library

Comment: You have to intialize array indexes first like `a = [[0,0,0]] * 3` or dynamically allocate memory using `append`.

Comment: Also `a = [[3 * r + c for c in range(3)] for r in range(3)]`. Look up list comprehensions. It's a way to create a list with preset values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate the memory dynamically using `append`. Also, `++num` will not do what you think here and you need `num += 1`.

```
num=1
a = []
for i in range(0,3):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(0,3):
        a[i].append(num)
        num += 1

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        print(str(a[i][j]) + " ", end="")
    print("\n")
```

Also, you should look at the numpy library which makes the matrix operations and linear algebra easy, efficient and optimized. The equivalent code in numpy would be:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
print(mat)
```

Comment: Good call prefix `++` is OK. It's the suffix version that causes syntax problems.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Recommend OP to look [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python)

Comment: but prefix ++ doesn't increment the value of variable

Comment: @Rupal. No one ever said it did. It just doesn't raise a SyntaxError.