# Pass a variable that increases as it is called?

Tags: python

How can I do this in python?

```
a = 0
func(a+=1) # a = 1
func(a+=1) # a = 2
```

Now I have had to solve it like this:

```
a = 0
a+=1
func(a)
a+=1
func(a)
...
```

and there must be a better way, right?

Edit:
Actually I also want to be able to pass it to different functions:

```
a = 0
a+=1
func1(a)
a+=1
func2(a)
a+=1
func1(a)
...
```

Comment: `res = [func(a) for a in range(n)]` ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python)

Comment: @jpp thanks, that worked but I realised I needed it to work for different functions

Comment: @ScottHunter I mean, writin a+=1 works, but I am calling like 30 functions in a test, and I would like it to be a bit smoother, by increasing the variable in the function call...

Comment: Ok, so define a function to return a function: `def switcher(a): return f(a); res = [switcher(a)(a) for a in range(n)]` where `f` is your logic. Your `switcher` can even be a dictionary and act like a dispatcher.

Comment: I updated my answer to decorate the functions as an alternative, inspired by @jpp

Answer (score 3):

your solution is okay, but if you want to have a counting side effect, use `itertools.count` object:

```
import itertools

def f(x):
    print(x)

c = itertools.count()
f(next(c))
f(next(c))
```

or the variant, performing the `next` call in the functions themselves (`itertools.counter` is mutable so you can modify it inside the function):

```
import itertools

def f(c):
    x = next(c)
    print(x)

c = itertools.count()
f(c)
f(c)
```

you can initialize it to a non-zero value: `c = itertools.count(3)`

Comment: Thaks! I went for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like this:

```
a = 0
a+=1;func1(a)
a+=1;func2(a)
```

Each line is only 2 characters longer than your original request.

Comment: I hadn't event thought about that I could to the increase and function call in the same line! Thanks for your answer, it helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in the sense that in Python, assignment is an instruction, not an operator whose operation returns a value.

You'll have to define a function and either use the `global` keyword with `a` or turn `a` into a mutable. You can also use a decorator for your functions.

```
a = [0]
#a = 0 # alternative version

def inc(x):
    x[0] += 1
    return x[0]

#    global a # alternative version
#    a += 1
#    return a


def f1(x):
    return x + 1

def f2(x):
    return x + 2


# or (inspired by @jpp comment) decorate your functions
def inc1(x):
    def inner(x):
        x[0] += 1
        return x[0]
    return inner

@inc1
def f3(x):
    return x


for i in range(10):
    print(inc(a))

print()
print(f1(inc(a)))
print(f2(inc(a)))

print()

a = [0]
print(f3(a))
print(f3(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a wrapping function that calls your function `f` and simultaneously increment the value of j!

```
>>> def f(a):print("Value of a is: %d"%a)
...
>>> c=lambda i:(i+1,f(i+1))
>>> j=0
>>> j,_=c(j)
Value of a is: 1
>>> j
1
>>> j,_=c(j)
Value of a is: 2
>>> j
2
```