# Will the below logic help in finding the number of occurrences of a sub string from a string?

Tags: python

For a hackerrank challenge to print the number of times that the substring occurs in the given string, I wrote attached logic.
But I keep receiving 0 has output. Please share comments on the logic where missing.

To print the number of times that the substring occurs in the given string

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        if(sub_string== string[i:i+len(sub_string)]):
            count= ++count 
    return count
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()

    count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
    print(count)
```

Input for string and sub_string is 
ABCDCDC,CDC

Expected output is 2, but the actual Result 0

Comment: Also note that you dont have to go all the way to `len(string)` lets say the length of the string is 10 and the length of the substring is 4, you would be checking 
`sub_string== string[9:13]` which never going to be true. You can save some iterations by doing `for i in range(0,len(string)-len(substring)+1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count=++count` does not work in Python (see e.g. [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python)), it should be `count+=1`, then your code works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Bug is in your `count = ++count` line
Change this to `count += 1`