# i+ =1 generating a Syntax error in for loop

Tags: python

eg.

```
name = 'python'
length = len(name)
i = 0
for n in range(-1,(-length-1), -1):
    print( name[i], '\t', name[n])
    i+ = 1
```

I remove the i+ = 1 which generates a semantic error. I'm a beginner and am using the python tutorial provided by the python website. Basically I'm practicing forward and backward indexing.

```
name = 'python'
length = len(name)
i = 0
for n in range(-1,(-length-1), -1):
    print( name[i], '\t', name[n])
    i+ = 1
```

I'm expecting it to run an output of the name forward then backwards

Comment: The loop is irrelevant. This program fails: `i = 0; i+ = 1`. So what should `i+ = 1` be changed to *validly* "increment the value of a variable"? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485854/2864740

Comment: Do `i += 1` instead

Comment: Davis, next time try to isolate your problems. Simply typing ```i+ = 1``` on python interpreter gives you the same error, and you already knew the problem was somewhat related to that. This is a good technique to find where the real problem is.

Comment: Apart from `i += 1`, you can also simplify for for loop a lot @DavisPaggett

Answer (score 2):

Your error lies in your `i+ = 1` statement, which should be `i += 1`

Try this:

```
name = 'python'
length = len(name)
i = 0
for n in range(-1,(-length-1), -1):
    print( name[i], '\t', name[n])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be no blank space between the + and =.

```
i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not arbitrarily spread spaces through your code. Certain tokens that Python recognizes have to be written exactly as they are documented. This is true for e.g. `class` that you can't write `cl a ss`, and it's also true for what you are using here wich is called an operator. It needs to be written `+=`, the same way `==` can't have a space in it etc.

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have already pointed out, the `+=` is used as `a += b` and not `a+ = b`, which the case you have when you do `i+ = 1`
For simplicity, and since you say you are a beginner, might I suggest using `i = i+1` instead.

In addition, you can also simplify your for loop by using `length` attribute to calculate the index from the end of the string. `range(length)` is the same as doing `range(0,length,1)`

```
name = 'python'
length = len(name)

i = 0
for i in range(length):
    print(name[i], '\t', name[length-i-1])
    i += 1
```

The output will be

```
p    n
y    o
t    h
h    t
o    y
n    p
```

Answer (score -1):

avoid space between + and =

use i+=1 instead i+ =1

refer here: [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python/1485854#1485854)

Comment: Please clarify your answer if you can. I don't see OP using `,,`