# Syntax error in if condition. Not equals sign highlighted

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this I get an invalid syntax error with the "=" part of the "!=" sign highlighted

I don't think it's a syntax problem on that line per say because I tried using a "==" sign and I still got the same error with the second "=" sign being highlighted

```
def delete(line_number):
    src = "userinfo.txt"
    dest = "tempfile.txt"
    counter = 1
    with open(src, "r") as input:
        with open(dest, "w") as output: 
            for line in input:
                if counter++ != line_number:
                    output.write(line)
```

Comment: Python doesn't have a `++` operator, so the sequence `++ !=` does not make sense.

Comment: if you need an index, use `for index, line in enumerate(input):`. In addition: `input` is not a good variable name, since it is a built-in function already.

Comment: @khelwood really misleading upvoted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486086/6260170

Comment: @Chris_Rands I agree

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't support incremental operated like other languages so you need to use `+` to increment your count.

```
def delete(line_number):
    src = "userinfo.txt"
    dest = "tempfile.txt"
    counter = 1
    with open(src, "r") as input:
        with open(dest, "w") as output: 
            for line in input:
                counter += 1
                if counter != line_number:
                    output.write(line)
```

> **NOTE:** `counter += 1` is same as `counter = counter + 1`.