# How to emulate the increment (++) operator?

Tags: python

My input is a list, say `l`

It can either contain 4 or 5 elements. I want to assign it to 5 variables , say `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`.

If the list has only 4 elements then the third variable (`c`) should be `None`.

If python had an increment (++) operator I could do something like this.

```
l = [4 or 5 string inputs]
i = -1
a = l[i++]
b = l[i++]
c = None
if len(l) > 4:
    c = l[i++]
d = l[i++]
e = l[i++]
```

I can't seem to find an elegant way to do this apart from writing `i+=1` before each assignment. Is there a simpler pythonic way to do this?

Comment: You could do `a, b, c, d, e = l` or `a, b, d, e = l`, depending on the length. Maybe there's even more pythonic solution

Comment: Aside from unpacking, is there anything wrong with referring to them in the list?

Comment: @AMC I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask if you can just use `my_list[0]`, `my_list[1]` etc. instead of assigning them to variables.

Comment: @AMC Yes I can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to use a C solution because you're unfamiliar with Python's tools. Using unpacking is much cleaner than trying to emulate `++`:

```
a, b, *c, d, e = l
c = c[0] if c else None
```

The `*c` target receives a list of all elements of `l` that weren't unpacked into the other targets. If this list is nonempty, then `c` is considered true when coerced to boolean, so `c[0] if c else None` takes `c[0]` if there is a `c[0]` and `None` otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

In the specific case of this question, [list unpacking is the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59697622/1399279).

For other users needing to emulate `++` for other purposes (typically the desire to increment without an explicit `i += 1` statement), they can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count). This will return an iterator that will increment indefinitely each time it is passed to `next()`.

```py
import itertools

i = itertools.count(0)  # start counting at 0
print(next(i))  # 0
print(next(i))  # 1
# ...and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that you really need to be incrementing at all since you have fixed positions for each variable subject to your c condition.

```
l = [4 or 5 string inputs]

a = l[0]
b = l[1]

if len(l) > 4:
    c = l[2]
    d = l[3]
    e = l[4]
else:
    c = None
    d = l[2]
    e = l[3]
```

Comment: I want to avoid doing stuff like  what you have done up there.

Comment: Stuff like what? And why?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ++ operator in Python. A similar question to this was answered here [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python)