# Mimic ++ operator for bookkeeping variable

Tags: python

For my application GUI (tkinter), I need a 'bookkeeping' variable that holds the current row number for a UI widget. I prefer not to hard code the row number because inserting a widget would involve renumbering all row numbers following it. In this situation, an increment operator (`x++`, similar to C++) would come in very handy, because incrementing the variable when necessary would require only two additional characters. However, Python [does not support increment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485854/12646289).

To avoid increment statement between elements that should go on different rows, I came up with the following solution but I am wondering what an alternative might be:

```
rownums = list(range(100))
rowstay = lambda: rownums[0]        # Return current row number and stay on row.
rowmove = lambda: rownums.pop(0)    # Return current row number and move on to next.

print(f'Two items: {rowstay()}, {rowmove()}')
print(f'One item: {rowmove()}')
print(f'Two items: {rowstay()}, {rowmove()}')
```

For example (tkinter):

```
# Create some buttons.
mybutton1 = tkinter.button(master, 'Button on row 0')
mybutton2 = tkinter.button(master, 'Button on row 0')
mybutton3 = tkinter.button(master, 'Button on row 1')


# Place buttons (use mimicked increment 'operator').
mybutton1.grid(row=rowstay(), column=0)
mybutton2.grid(row=rowmove(), column=1)
mybutton3.grid(row=rowmove(), column=0)
```

What alternative code would provide the same functionality?

Comment: Python has `+= 1` which is equivalent to `++`.

Comment: Having lambdas with hard-coded variables seems very unclean. You'll need to repeat this for every variable you want to be able to increment. Either define functions that take parameters or define a class.

Comment: To add to what @Barmar said, you can also define a lambda function that takes an input: `lambda x: rownums.pop(x)`.

Comment: If you define a class, you can define the `__iadd__` method, which implements the `+=` operator, and then you can write `rownums +=  1`

Comment: This is a very weird question.  Having the equal signs and dots line up is not important.  Also, assigning `lamba`s to variables is [unpythonic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: Anyway, this question isn't really appropriate for SO. It's a question about programming style, which is a matter of opinion. [softwareengineering.se] or [codereview.se] might be more appropriate.

Comment: What's weird about it? According to PEP8 [https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/] vertical alignment for increased legibility is a serious consideration. When I am positioning widgets, it is very helpful to have row and column arguments aligned.

Comment: @Jan-WillemL well, the thing that is against PEP8 is assigning a lambda to a name. Don't do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incrementing a counter while assigning it in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022643/incrementing-a-counter-while-assigning-it-in-python)

Comment: Actually, it does, but as pointed in the answer, it is not the recommended way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments and answer, I learned that mutating with a lambda and assigning lambdas is not Pythonic. Several comments suggest using `+= 1` but this is exactly what I wanted to avoid because it requires an additional statement for each time the variable should be incremented. <s>The solution with higher order functions (or a class) mimics `++x` instead of `x++`.</s>

My solution (second-best, see better solution under **EDIT**):

```py
class BookkeepingVar():
    """ Variable with the ++-operator from C++ mimicked.

        Example:
        x = BookkeepingVar(0)
        y = x() + 1    # y = 1, x = 1 
        z = x(1) + 1   # z = 1, x = 2 
    """

    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.var = [start]

    def __call__(self, incr=0):
        if incr:
            self.var.append(self.var[0] + incr)
            return self.var.pop(0)
        else:
            return self.var[0]
```

Example usage:

```py
# Create some buttons.
mybutton1 = tkinter.button(master, 'Button on row 0')
mybutton2 = tkinter.button(master, 'Button on row 0')
mybutton3 = tkinter.button(master, 'Button on row 1')

# Place buttons.
row = BookkeepingVar(0)
mybutton1.grid(row=row(0), column=0)
mybutton2.grid(row=row(1), column=1)
mybutton3.grid(row=row(1), column=0)
```

Please note:

1. There's no upper bound to the variable value (as in the lambda example).
2. The list length never exceeds two, so I can't imagine inefficiencies of `pop()` to be problematic.
3. The solution is slightly more general than mimicking `x++` only because it also supports increments other than 1.
4. The solution also supports decrements (use a negative argument).
5. The `__call__` method was implemented in order to make notation as short as possible.

**EDIT:**

A simpler and more elegant solution without list (same usage):

```py
class BookkeepingVar():
    """ Variable with the ++-operator from C++ mimicked.

        Example:
        x = BookkeepingVar(0)
        y = x() + 1    # y = 1, x = 1 
        z = x(1) + 1   # z = 1, x = 2 
    """
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.var = start

    def __call__(self, incr=0):
        self.var += incr
        return self.var - incr
```

**EDIT 2**:
Remark about `++x` vs. `x++` (strikethrough).

Comment: Given you apparently don't use things like rowspan, I'd have the custom object be in charge of the entire thing and call `grid` internally e.g. `layout = Layout(); layout.row(mybutton1, mybutton2); layout.row(mybutton3)`. And `layout` could keep track of the current row using either a regular integer or an `itertools.count()`. Obviously if you're using a more complex layout than just a bunch of rows that doesn't work. Though you could probably have something even more declarative.