# Incrementing a counter while assigning it in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to do the following in python somehow?

```
nodename = 'node%s' % (++num if ct[0] != 'J' else num)
```

Or do I need to first do the increment and the assign it on the next line:

```
if ct[0] != 'J':
    num += 1
    nodename = 'node%s' % num
```

Comment: To be clear, Python does not have a `++` operator, and in languages which do, the post-increment form `num++` evaluates to `num`'s original value, not its new value; so `nodename = 'node%s' % num` followed by `if ct[0] != 'J': num += 1` in Python would have the same behaviour as an analogous expression would in Java. But that is not the behaviour of your second sample code (which seems to be using `ct` itself in the string formatting expression?).

Comment: `enumerate()` is your friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3.8+ has the [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), which allows you to assign to a variable within an expression. The expression `var := expr` assigns the value of `expr` to `var`, and results in that same value.

This means the **pre-increment operator** `++var` can be simulated in Python by `var := var + 1`. This increments `var` and the result is the new, incremented value of `var`. This seems to be the behaviour you are looking for.

In languages which have these operators, the **post-increment operator** `var++` has different behaviour; it increments `var`, but the value of the expression `var++` is the old, un-incremented value of `var`. From your code sample, this doesn't seem to be the behaviour you're looking for, but for completeness, it can be simulated in Python by `(var, var := var + 1)[0]`. This evaluates to a tuple containing the old value of `var` and the new value of `var` after doing the increment, and then gets the first component of that tuple (i.e. the old, un-incremented value).

That said, I would recommend against using the former, and *strongly* recommend against the latter, since it's highly non-idiomatic in Python. If you want to do two different things (i.e. increment `num` and format a string), it is more readable and understandable if you do them separately.