# Python incremental int inplace ++ vs +=

Tags: python, syntax

```
self.test1 = input[column += 1]
```

Error

```
self.test1 = input[column += 1]
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Put the increment on its own line.

Comment: `column += 1` is not an expression in Python. It does not have a value and cannot be used as an index.

Comment: See explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python

Comment: I don't see a question here? What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`column += 1` can not be used in the way you are using it because it is a statement rather than an expression.

What you are writing is equivalent to `self.test1 = input[column = column + 1]` which doesn't much sense.

Instead you would need to do:

```
column += 1
self.test1 = input[column]
```

or

```
self.test1 = input[column]
column += 1
```

depends on which one you were looking for.

---

Also, since you asked in your title, `++` or `--` does not exist in python.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean one of these:

```
self.test1 = input[column + 1]
```

or

```
column += 1
self.test1 = input[column]
```

or

```
self.test1 = input[column]
column += 1
```

the `column +=1` can not appear in code like what you wrote, because it doesn't have/return a value.

In C/C++ you can have that expression, but even that should be used [carefully](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). In Python there is no operation like that.

Comment: Wanna say that `column += 1` cannot be used in this scenario either in C++, and I would assume it's the same in C. The reason is that `column += 1` is equivalent to `column = column + 1`, which doesn't make much sense to put it there.

Comment: Instead you were probably looking for `column++` and `++column`. And like you said, those need to be used carefully since the first one is reassigning `column` after the line, and the second one is reassigning `column` first