# How does the following expression work in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How does the following expression work in python?

```
>>> 1 ++++++++++++++++++++ 1
2
>>> 1 ++++++++++++++++++++-+ 1
0
```

I thought this would raise a `SyntaxError` but that was not the case.

Comment: In general, pass the expression through `import ast; print(ast.dump(ast.parse('1 +++-+ 1', mode='eval'), indent=4))` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use the logic of brackets and arithmetic operations for this kind of calculation.

1--2 becomes,

```
1-(-(2)) = 1-(-2)
         = 1+2
         = 3
```

1+++1 becomes,

```
1+(+(+1)) = 2
```

1++-1 becomes,

```
1+(+(-1)) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no `post / pre increment / decrement operators` in python.

We can see `++` or `--` as multiple signs getting multiplied, like we do in maths. `(-1) * (-1) = (+1).`

So the first expression will evaluate to `(1)+ (+1)= 2`

the other one, `(+1) + -(+1)=(+1)-(+1)=1-1=0`

For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

It's amazing that you are playing with python. At first I was also astonished. But thinking it deeply, It's just simple math! It doesn't matter how many plus you are giving in front of a number. It stays the same.

```
++++++++++++++(1) = 1
```

But it matters if there is any minus.

```
+++++++++-(1) = -1
```

(parenthesis is just for clearness) So in your code at the first one the value doesn't change because there is just plus. But in the second one the value of 1 changes to -1 because there is a minus. So the result is zero. But if there was two minus, the result would be 2. Because -- = +.

```
>>> 1 +++++++++++++-- 1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Python [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=invert#object.__neg__) and [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). You find the magic methods `__neg__`, `__pos__`, `__abs__`, and `__invert__` all take a single argument. Other than `__abs__`, these are implemented as operators, `-` for `__neg__`, `+` for `__pos__`, and `~` for `__invert__`. Looking at operator precedence, these bind more tightly than any binary arithmetic operators. `__pos__` just returns the int unchanged, whereas `__neg__` returns the same int but with its sign changed. So the interpreter is just repeatedly applying that operation over and over until it finally finds a left operand and actually does some arithmetic.