# b = a*+2 is valid syntax. Why?

Tags: python, syntax

Why does python (3.7.9) allow this syntax?

```
a = 3
b = a*+2
```

It find this annoying because if you want to type
`b = a**2` it can happen very quickly on the german keyboard layout that you write instead `b = a*+2`. With no sytnax error, finding such a bug can be very time consuming. Furthermore, it violates the usual mathematical rule that adjacent operators should be separated with brackets.

Comment: This is a very compelling reason to practice touch-typing.

Comment: That's allowed in many other languages (e.g. C, Go, JavaScript).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because python [supports unary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations). You can also inspect how python compiles down the source expression to [abstract syntax tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)  using `ast` module.

```
>>> import ast
>>>
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("b = a*+2"), indent=4))
Module(
    body=[
        Assign(
            targets=[
                Name(id='b', ctx=Store())],
            value=BinOp(
                left=Name(id='a', ctx=Load()),
                op=Mult(),
                right=UnaryOp(
                    op=UAdd(),
                    operand=Constant(value=2))))],
    type_ignores=[])
```

See also:

- [How does the following expression work in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527272/how-does-the-following-expression-work-in-python)