# How to add a number to a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
num1 = 29
num1 + 1
print(num1)
```

Output is 29 , but i want num1 to be 30

Comment: You didn't assign the result of `num1 + 1` to a name.  Try `num1 = num1 + 1` instead.

Comment: try this `num1 += 1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You assigned `num1` to `29`. So, when you print `num1`, `29` would be the output. Try assigning the answer as `"sum"`.

```
num1=29
sum = num1 + 1
print(sum)
```

This should show the correct answer.