# Any way to change variable within another variable that is being changed?

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I need to change the value of `nValor` on the same line that I'm messing with `cInText`

the desired way of doing:

```
cText = "Something"
nValor = len(cText)-1
cInText = ""
while nValor >= 0:
    cInText += cText[nValor -= 1]
print(cInText)
```

the unwanted way of doing:

```
cText = "Something"
nValor = len(cText)-1
cInText = ""
while nValor >= 0:
    cInTexto += cTexto[nValor]
    nValor -= 1
print(cInTexto)
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your second excerpt it seems you ideally want *post-decrement* operator behaviour, but Python has neither pre- nor post-increment/decrement operators. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python) and answers for details.

You can, however, get desired behaviour by using multiple-target [assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) like this:

```
cInText, nValor = cInText + cText[nValor], nValor - 1
```

First, right-hand side will be evaluated to a tuple of 2 elements, after which 2 comma-separated targets will be assigned to respective tuple elements.

If you want *pre-decrement* behaviour however (as suggested by your first example), since Python 3.8 you can use [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) (walrus assignment) like this:

```
cInText += cText[nValor := nValor - 1]
```

Here, value of expression `nValor := nValor - 1` is just `nValor - 1`, but as a side-effect this expression also assigns this value to `nValor`, as desired.

Note that in your case post-decrement behaviour is needed if you want to reverse `cInText` (otherwise, `nValor` indexes will be incorrect and result in negative index on the last iteration). Also, if this is not a toy example and your original problem is to do a reverse, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python) and answers.