# python object to accept len function to run against it

Tags: python, function

I have a python object which stores details of countries, what method should I implement to allow running the object into len(ObjectInstance)?

For example, I want to count all the countries in the instance and I must use len() the function because its a third party call/external.

How can I implement a method that would be called when len() is executed against the instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `__len__()` magic method:

```
>>> class A():
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 100
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> len(a)
100
```

Also see:

- [Making Custom Sequences](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#sequence) paragraph of "A Guide to Python's Magic Methods"
- [Why does python use 'magic methods'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657627/why-does-python-use-magic-methods)
- [difference between len() and .__len__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481421/difference-between-len-and-len)