# How to setup commands which require client functions(please read description)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to set up a latency command in a cog but it isn't possible since there's no client attribute in a cog, upon using `self.client.latency` it still gives a error

```
class misc(commands.Cog):
    def _init_(self , client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(misc(client))
```

and the error is
 `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'misc' object has no attribute 'client'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a class make sure you add two undescores in `init` function eg: `__init__` instead of `_init_`.

Methods with __ are known as dunder or magic methods in python.
Read these for more info on them:

[Why do we use **init** in Python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes)

[Why does Python use 'magic methods'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657627/why-does-python-use-magic-methods)