# Why len(list) instead of list.len() in python?

Tags: python, list

Might be a weird question. But I have been scratching my head over why if you want to get the length of a list you can't simply say list.len() and you have to pass the list to len() to get its size? And where this len() is actually coming from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a reason Python strings don't have a string length method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237128/is-there-a-reason-python-strings-dont-have-a-string-length-method)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the length of a lot of items. Lists, dicts, sets, other collections. So the [builtin `len()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) that calls `type(obj).__len__(obj)` internally gives you a standard API to get the length.

If all those collection types had a `len()` method that was called directly there would be nothing to prevent someone from creating a custom collection class that uses e.g. `.length()` or a `.length` property.

[Here's](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-November/004643.html) the explanation from Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python:

> First of all, I chose `len(x)` over `x.len()` for HCI reasons (`def __len__()` came much later). There are two intertwined reasons actually, both HCI:
>
> (a) For some operations, prefix notation just reads better than
>   postfix -- prefix (and infix!) operations have a long tradition in
>   mathematics which likes notations where the visuals help the
>   mathematician thinking about a problem. Compare the easy with which we
>   rewrite a formula like `x*(a+b)` into `x*a + x*b` to the clumsiness of
>   doing the same thing using a raw OO notation.
>
> (b) When I read code that says `len(x)` I *know* that it is asking for
>   the length of something. This tells me two things: the result is an
>   integer, and the argument is some kind of container. To the contrary,
>   when I read `x.len()`, I have to already know that x is some kind of
>   container implementing an interface or inheriting from a class that
>   has a standard `len()`. Witness the confusion we occasionally have when
>   a class that is not implementing a mapping has a `get()` or `keys()`
>   method, or something that isn't a file has a `write()` method.
>
> Saying the same thing in another way, I see 'len' as a built-in
>   *operation*. I'd hate to lose that. I can't say for sure whether you meant that or not, but 'def len(self): ...' certainly sounds like you
>   want to demote it to an ordinary method. I'm strongly -1 on that.

Comment: Using len(obj) instead of an objects property 'length' sounds more Pythonian to me as well, it even makes sense when read aloud.

Answer (score 5):

it actually comes from `__len__()`:

```
In [15]: lis=[1,2,3]

In [16]: lis.__len__()
Out[16]: 3
```

[`object.__len__(self)`:](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__)

> Called to implement the built-in function len().
>   Should return the length of the object, an integer >= 0. Also, an
>   object that doesn’t define a **nonzero**() method and whose **len**()
>   method returns zero is considered to be false in a Boolean context.