# How to count letters in a string inputted by a user in Python..?

Tags: python, import, pyscripter

There are many related questions to this, although they do not explain how to take words inputted by the user and use them in an equation. How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a reason Python strings don't have a string length method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237128/is-there-a-reason-python-strings-dont-have-a-string-length-method)

Comment: What have you tried? What questions have you looked at, and what part do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean find the length of the string use len("string")

if you want to find the number of letters of a distinct type use counter

```
from collections import Counter 
a = Counter("stringsss")
print a['s']
```