# Differences of where to put the variable: variable_name.upper( ) vs. len(variable_name)

Tags: python, string, function, methods, formatting

Why in the methods `len( )`, the placement of variables different from the others, for example the`upper( )`

```
# with len()
len(variable_name)

# with upper()
variable_name.upper()
```

Things may be trivial , it makes me uncomfortable if do not know it ... thanks.

Comment: `len` is a Python ["built-in *function*"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) that is a general operation that works for sequences; strings can be thought of a sequence of characters. There are only a few such built-in functions, selected largely due to their general usefulness. `str.upper` is a string-specific *method*; as is [`str.__len__` which implements the "\_\_len\_\_ protocol" required for `len`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237128/is-there-a-reason-python-strings-dont-have-a-string-length-method).

Answer (score 0):

`variable_name.upper()` is calling a method of the `variable_name` class or an inherited class.

`len(variable_name)` is calling Python's built-in `len` function on a `variable_name` object for which the `len` function determines the length depending on the type of object, be it a `str` or `list` for example.

So the placement of the `variable_name` tells you if you are calling a class attribute (`variable_name` in front) OR you are passing a variable into a method which is not an attribute of the `variable_name` class (`variable_name` in the brackets).