# Python len() method not returning value

Tags: python

I have started learning python programming language and learning string in python.

i am using following code to find the length of string.

```
a = "Hello, World!"
print(a.len())
```

but code is not working. I know i am using method len after variable. But why other method works after variable? E.G print(a.lower()) to lower sting, print(a.upper()) to upper string

Comment: `a.len()` doesn't exist. `len(a)` does.

Comment: `len(string)` is mentioned in [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: FYI only: "not working" is often a 100% correct description of a problem. However, it is also virtually useless. For any next questions: Python gives quite an *extensive* output error message when you make an error. Make sure to include this in your post.

Comment: As to "why": duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/237128/2564301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `a.len()` doesn't exist. You should do

```
a = "Hello, World!"
print(len(a))
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

dot notations such us `.upper(), .lower()` are methods and `len(), abs()` etc are functions
Use `len(a)` instead

Answer (score 0):

It should work across all the Version starting 2.6, reason its not working as mentioned you are trying it wrong as `a.len()` !

Python 2.6

```
>>> a = "Hello, World!"
>>> print len(a)
13
```

Python 3

```
>>> a = "Hello, World!"
>>> print(len(a))
13
```

Python 2.7

```
>>> a = "Hello, World!"
>>> print(len(a))
13
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @Alex44, always Welcome .. happy learning!