# Basic question on Python ? Why we are using () and . sometimes?

Tags: python

Suppose we have

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

for checking the type of a, we used this function

```
type(a)
```

to check the type of attribute, we used this

```
a.dtype
```

Why in the first case we used `type(a)` and in the second case we used `a.dtype` and why not `dtype(a)`
I have seen this many times in other libraries too. Kindly explain me the basics of it.

Comment: We use dot notation to access _properties_ of objects (e.g. `a.dtype` accesses the property `dtype` of the object `a`). If those properties (or any object) happen to also be functions, we can _call_ them with the parentheses (`np.array([1, 2, 3])` calls the function `np.array` with the argument `[1, 2, 3]`)

Comment: bcz `dtype` is an attribute and `type()` is a method

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy exactly so, except swap every use of the word "property" with "attribute." (A property is a specific _type_ of attribute)

Comment: The obvious reason why we sometimes use method-call syntax and sometimes function-call syntax, is that some things are methods and other are functions. [This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237128/why-does-python-code-use-len-function-instead-of-a-length-method) contains some discussion about how that situation came to be.

Comment: Does that mean, functions which are not in any class, are used like type(a) and whereas if we want to use a function which is in a class, we have to use a.dtype ? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Anurag `type` is a *function*!

Answer (score 2):

`type(a)` is a builtin function that gives the type of the object `a`

`a.dtype` is using attribute access to access the attribute `dtype` of the object `a`, which in the case of `np.array` is the type of data contained in `a`.

Comment: Non-member functions often delegate to the magic methods.

Comment: Yes and I believe `type(a)` is synonymous with `a.__type__` (like `help(a) == a.__doc__`, `vars(a) == a.__dict__`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you write `type(a)`, you are calling the function `type()`, which gives the type of its `parameter`. (You need the `()` to call the function)
With `a.dtype`, `a` is an instance, and `dtype` is a `method` in that class. (The "." is there to show the code that the method `dtype` is in the same class with the instance `a`)

Here is a useful link that explains it;
https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5170307264a7402d9a0012f5

Answer (score 0):

in case `type(a)` the `a` is the parameter for the method
also `[1,2,3]` in `a = np.array([1,2,3])`
but in case `a.dtype`, `dtype` may be a method of class or maybe a function