# Why did Python 2.6 add a global next() function?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I noticed that Python2.6 added a next() to it's [list of global functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

> [`next(iterator[, default])`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next)
>
> ```
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its next() method.
> ```
>
> If `default` is given, it is returned if
>   the iterator is exhausted, otherwise
>   `StopIteration` is raised.

What was the motivation for adding this?
What can you do with `next(iterator)` that you can't do with `iterator.next()` and an `except` clause to handle the StopIteration?

Answer (score 18):

It's just for consistency with functions like `len()`. I believe `next(i)` calls `i.__next__()` internally.

See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/

Comment: +1. The same reason Python has a built-in len() function.  See the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83983/why-isnt-the-len-function-inherited-by-dictionaries-and-lists-in-python for the link to Guido's rationale.

Answer (score 10):

Note that in Python 3.0+ the `next` method has been renamed to `__next__`. This is because of consistency. `next` is a special method and special methods are named by convention (PEP 8) with double leading and trailing underscore. Special methods are not meant to be called directly, that's why the `next` built in function was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

It calls `__next__` internally, but it makes it look more 'functional' than 'object-oriented'.  Mind you that's just my opinion, but I don't like `next(i)` rather than `i.next()`. But as Steve Mc said, it also helps slightly with consistency.