# Python: Why should I use next() and not obj.next()?

Tags: python, iterator, built-in

Python 2.6 introduced a `next` function.

Why was this necessary? One could always type `obj.next()` instead of `next(obj)`.

Is the latter more `pythonic`?

Comment: I've always wondered why the Monty Python-inspired Python language felt the need to coin the term "pythonic" instead of the more natural "Pythonesque".....

Comment: Also asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656155/why-did-python-2-6-add-a-global-next-function

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[PEP 3114](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/) describes this change. An excerpt about the motivation:

> This PEP proposes that the `next` method be renamed to `__next__`,
>   consistent with all the other protocols in Python in which a method is
>   implicitly called as part of a language-level protocol, and that a
>   built-in function named `next` be introduced to invoke `__next__` method,
>   consistent with the manner in which other protocols are explicitly
>   invoked.

Be sure to read this PEP for more interesting details.

As for why *you* want to use the `next` built-in: one good reason is that the `next` method disappears in Python 3, so for portability it's better to start using the `next` built-in as soon as possible.

Comment: I liked this answer most. Especially because of the note, that Py3000 won't have next methods on objects anymore.

Answer (score 28):

> [`next(iterator[, default])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next)
>
> Retrieve the next item from the *iterator* by calling its `next()`<sup>`(__next__()` in python 3)</sup> method. If *default* is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise `StopIteration` is raised.

You get the `default` option.

Comment: +1, but couldn't one then simply have added an optional `default` parameter to the method: `obj.next(default)`?

Comment: @Tim: Then every iterator implementation would have to duplicate the logic.

Comment: Also, in Python 3 the `next()` method does not exist anymore. It is replaced by `__next__()`. The `next()` function allows a unified behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

Apart from the obvious additional functionality, it also looks better when used together with generator expressions. Compare

```
(x for x in lst if x > 2).next()
```

to

```
next(x for x in lst if x > 2)
```

The latter is a lot more consistent with the rest of Python's style, IMHO.

Comment: Doesn't the generator expression start over from the beginning each time the statement is executed? Seems like this would only ever return the first element.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, that's the purpose of this idiom: Return the first element from an iterable that meets a certain criterion (or raise `StopIteration` otherwise).

Comment: It's like `Enumerable#find` in Ruby, for example.