# difference between the next function and the next method

Tags: python

When you make a generator by calling a function or method that has the `yield` keyword in it you get an object that has a `next` method.

So far as I can tell, there isn't a difference between using this method and using the `next` builtin function.

e.g. `my_generator.next()` vs `next(my_generator)`

So is there any difference? If not, why are there two ways of calling next on a generator?

Comment: This question may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414210/python-why-should-i-use-next-and-not-obj-next It looks like the two exist for backward compatability reasons, but next() is the more appropriate _pythonic_ way

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 the internal method for an iterator is `next()` in Python 3 it is `__next__()`. The builtin function `next()` is aware of this and always calls the right method making the code compatible with both versions. Also it adds the `default` argument for more easy handling of the iteration end.